# ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a controller action that effectively simply returns a JsonResult of my model. So, in my method I have something like the following:

```
return new JsonResult(myModel);
```

This works well, except for one problem. There is a date property in the model and this appears to be returned in the Json result like so:

```
"\/Date(1239018869048)\/"
```

How should I be dealing with dates so they are returned in the format I require? Or how do I handle this format above in script?

Comment: I have posted my json net result to the same problem, it converts the date to iso format making it much easier to work with.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778599/knockout-dates-being-reset-on-post-to-mvc-controller/15799992#15799992

Comment: Please look into this below link. Straight Forward. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60392503/5962626

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Just to expand on [casperOne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-mvc-jsonresult-date-format/726417#726417).

The [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) does not account for Date values. MS had to make a call, and the path they chose was to exploit a little trick in the javascript representation of strings: the string literal "/" is the same as "\/", and a string literal will *never* get serialized to "\/" (even "\/" must be mapped to "\\/").

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx#intro_to_json_topic2 for a better explanation (scroll down to "From JavaScript Literals to JSON")

> One of the sore points of JSON is the
>   lack of a date/time literal. Many
>   people are surprised and disappointed
>   to learn this when they first
>   encounter JSON. The simple explanation
>   (consoling or not) for the absence of
>   a date/time literal is that JavaScript
>   never had one either: The support for
>   date and time values in JavaScript is
>   entirely provided through the Date
>   object. Most applications using JSON
>   as a data format, therefore, generally
>   tend to use either a string or a
>   number to express date and time
>   values. If a string is used, you can
>   generally expect it to be in the ISO
>   8601 format. If a number is used,
>   instead, then the value is usually
>   taken to mean the number of
>   milliseconds in Universal Coordinated
>   Time (UTC) since epoch, where epoch is
>   defined as midnight January 1, 1970
>   (UTC). Again, this is a mere
>   convention and not part of the JSON
>   standard. If you are exchanging data
>   with another application, you will
>   need to check its documentation to see
>   how it encodes date and time values
>   within a JSON literal. For example,
>   Microsoft's ASP.NET AJAX uses neither
>   of the described conventions. Rather,
>   it encodes .NET DateTime values as a
>   JSON string, where the content of the
>   string is /Date(ticks)/ and where
>   ticks represents milliseconds since
>   epoch (UTC). So November 29, 1989,
>   4:55:30 AM, in UTC is encoded as
>   "\/Date(628318530718)\/".

A solution would be to just parse it out:

```
value = new Date(parseInt(value.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));
```

However I've heard that there is a setting somewhere to get the serializer to output `DateTime` objects with the `new Date(xxx)` syntax. I'll try to dig that out.

---

The second parameter of `JSON.parse()` accepts a `reviver` function where prescribes how the value originally produced by, before being returned.

Here is an example for date:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(data, function(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    var d = /\/Date\((\d*)\)\//.exec(value);
    return (d) ? new Date(+d[1]) : value;
  }
  return value;
});
```

See the docs of [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Thanks, where would the parsing go though?

Comment: The code I posted is JavaScript. You would put it in your client code.

Comment: You can shorten the js to 
new Date(parseInt(dateString.replace(/\/Date\\((\d+)\\)\//gi, "$1")))

Comment: In fact the regex is more correct as

replace(/\/Date\\((-?\d+)\\)\//gi, "$1")

since the date may be represented as a -ve number too

Comment: can anyone tell me what is meaning of that 10 in your first option

Comment: @HarshilShah That is the second argument for `parseInt()`. It tells the function to extract an integer in base 10 numeral system. It's a radix. If you put `8` in there, it would extract an octal number.

Comment: The regex ignores dates before 1970. To allow for all dates in the ECMAScript date range, it should include a possible leading minus sign: `/\/Date\((-?\d*)\)\//`.

Comment: I used `Moment.js`, here's a reference in the parsing [secction](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/)

Comment: Great way to parse it but, How would i pack it up and send it back?

Comment: `value = new Date(parseInt(value.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));` worked for me perfectly

Answer (score 109):

Here's my solution in Javascript - very much like JPot's, but shorter (and possibly a tiny bit faster):

```
value = new Date(parseInt(value.substr(6)));
```

"value.substr(6)" takes out the "/Date(" part, and the parseInt function ignores the non-number characters that occur at the end.

EDIT: I have intentionally left out the radix (the 2nd argument to parseInt); see [my comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format/1767558#comment23310086_1767558). Also, please note that ISO-8601 dates are preferred over this old format -- so this format generally shouldn't be used for new development.

For ISO-8601 formatted JSON dates, just pass the string into the Date constructor:

```
var date = new Date(jsonDate); //no ugly parsing needed; full timezone support
```

Comment: +1 I took your simple solution and put it in a recursive function. See here: http://danielsadventure.info/dotnetdatetime/

Comment: You should always specify a radix when using parseInt. [Source]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: @JohnZabroski: Every rule has its exceptions. The .NET date serializer _never_ returns integers with leading zeroes, so we can safely leave out the radix.

Comment: We had almost the same thing. We used `value.substr(6, 13)` for removing the other non number characters. But if you do that, all the dates BEFORE 04/26/1938 are invalid! We didn't knew `parseInt` would ignore the non number characters. Thanks!

Comment: @RalphJansen—don't use `substr(6,13)` as it will truncate the value for dates before 1970 which will have a leading minus `-`. ;-)

Comment: @JohnZabroski—`parseInt` should ignore leading zeros as of [*ECMAScript ed 5*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-parseint-string-radix) (2011).

Comment: Doesn't take into account timezones e.g. "\/Date(1239018869048+0100)\/"

Comment: @ct5845: Please see above - you shouldn't be using this old format for new code. Use the ISO-8601 format. The Json.NET library makes it easy.

Answer (score 71):

There are quite a bit of answers to handle it client side, but you can change the output server side if you desired.

There are a few ways to approach this, I'll start with the basics. You'll have to subclass the JsonResult class and override the ExecuteResult method. From there you can take a few different approaches to change the serialization.

**Approach 1:**
The default implementation uses the [JsonScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). If you take a look at the documentation, you can use the RegisterConverters method to add custom [JavaScriptConverters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx). There are a few problems with this though: The JavaScriptConverter serializes to a dictionary, that is it takes an object and serializes to a Json dictionary. In order to make the object serialize to a string it requires a bit of hackery, see [post](http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2011/12/custom-datetime-json-serialization/). This particular hack will also escape the string.

```
public class CustomJsonResult : JsonResult
{
    private const string _dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
        {
            response.ContentType = ContentType;
        }
        else
        {
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
        if (ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
        }
        if (Data != null)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            // Use your custom JavaScriptConverter subclass here.
            serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavascriptConverter[] { new CustomConverter });

            response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Data));
        }
    }
}
```

**Approach 2 (recommended):**
The second approach is to start with the overridden JsonResult and go with another Json serializer, in my case the [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) serializer. This doesn't require the hackery of approach 1. Here is my implementation of the JsonResult subclass:

```
public class CustomJsonResult : JsonResult
{
    private const string _dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
        {
            response.ContentType = ContentType;
        }
        else
        {
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
        if (ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
        }
        if (Data != null)
        {
            // Using Json.NET serializer
            var isoConvert = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
            isoConvert.DateTimeFormat = _dateFormat;
            response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, isoConvert));
        }
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index() {
    return new CustomJsonResult { Data = new { users=db.Users.ToList(); } };
}
```

**Additional credits:**
[James Newton-King](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net.aspx)

Comment: And what about the others formats like monetary, identification numbers, telephone, and so on ? Doesn't be a better aproach to get these formats from ModelMetadata and use them to serialize Models to Json ? How ?

Comment: This is the best solution (Perishable Dave's answer). The server is responsable of giving the correct date format. Also having a custom JsonResult gives many more benefits and control.  I would suggest implementing a helper method "CustomJson(data)" that instantiates CustomJsonResult as there exists "Json(data)", which instantiates JsonResult with its data.

Comment: One correction needed if you use either of these approaches - the first line should be:
private const string _dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss";
I added the "T".

Comment: James Newton-King provided a `JsonNetResult` class example here http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net which is similar to Approach 2 and gives access to a complete JsonSerializerSettings property.

Answer (score 32):

Moment.js is an extensive datetime library that also supports this. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-dates/

ex: moment("/Date(1198908717056-0700)/")

It might help. [plunker output](http://embed.plnkr.co/P05l1a/preview)

Comment: First Download moment.js file. Add in your project than use `moment("json_date_string_value").format('appropriate format');` 
you can see different format values on momet.js page

Answer (score 25):

I found that creating a new `JsonResult` and returning that is unsatisfactory - having to replace all calls to `return Json(obj)` with `return new MyJsonResult { Data = obj }` is a pain.

---

So I figured, why not just hijack the `JsonResult` using an `ActionFilter`:

```
public class JsonNetFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result is JsonResult == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        filterContext.Result = new JsonNetResult(
            (JsonResult)filterContext.Result);
    }

    private class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
    {
        public JsonNetResult(JsonResult jsonResult)
        {
            this.ContentEncoding = jsonResult.ContentEncoding;
            this.ContentType = jsonResult.ContentType;
            this.Data = jsonResult.Data;
            this.JsonRequestBehavior = jsonResult.JsonRequestBehavior;
            this.MaxJsonLength = jsonResult.MaxJsonLength;
            this.RecursionLimit = jsonResult.RecursionLimit;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }

            var isMethodGet = string.Equals(
                context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, 
                "GET", 
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            if (this.JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
                && isMethodGet)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "GET not allowed! Change JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.");
            }

            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            response.ContentType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ContentType) 
                ? "application/json" 
                : this.ContentType;

            if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
            {
                response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;
            }

            if (this.Data != null)
            {
                response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Data));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

This can be applied to any method returning a `JsonResult` to use JSON.Net instead:

```
[JsonNetFilter]
public ActionResult GetJson()
{
    return Json(new { hello = new Date(2015, 03, 09) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}
```

which will respond with

```
{"hello":"2015-03-09T00:00:00+00:00"}
```

as desired!

---

You can, if you don't mind calling the `is` comparison at every request, add this to your `FilterConfig`:

```
// ...
filters.Add(new JsonNetFilterAttribute());
```

and all of your JSON will now be serialized with JSON.Net instead of the built-in `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Comment: This is the only one answer that provides a solid approach (can be set as global or granular) without strange javascript inline. Can i upvote twice?

Comment: This is the real answer to the question, giving options to your needs in an easy and concise way to understand it. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

### Using jQuery to auto-convert dates with `$.parseJSON`

> ***Note***: this answer provides a jQuery extension that adds automatic ISO and .net date format support.

Since you're using Asp.net MVC I suspect you're using jQuery on the client side. I suggest you read [this blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/converting-dates-in-json-strings-using.html) that has code how to use `$.parseJSON` to automatically convert dates for you.

Code supports Asp.net formatted dates like the ones you mentioned as well as ISO formatted dates. All dates will be automatically formatted for you by using `$.parseJSON()`.

Comment: At first I thought this approach worked very well.  (See comments at end of article for how to register a converter in $.ajaxSetup())  However, a big downside to this solution is that it does not support dates before Epoc (1970).....   so now I've decided to just give up on .asmx files and switch to WebAPI which formats dates better (using JSON.NET) and will circumvent all this trouble.

Answer (score 14):

Ajax communication between the client and the server often involves data in JSON format. While JSON works well for strings, numbers and Booleans it can pose some difficulties for dates due to the way ASP.NET serializes them. As it doesn't have any special representation for dates, they are serialized as plain strings. 
As a solution the default serialization mechanism of ASP.NET Web Forms and MVC serializes dates in a special form - /Date(ticks)/- where ticks is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970.

This problem can be solved in 2 ways:

**client side**

Convert the received date string into a number and create a date object using the constructor of the date class with the ticks as parameter.

```
function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
  var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
  var results = pattern.exec(value);
  var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
  return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
}
```

**server side**

The previous solution uses a client side script to convert the date to a JavaScript Date object. You can also use server side code that serializes .NET DateTime instances in the format of your choice.
To accomplish this task you need to create your own ActionResult and then serialize the data the way you want.

reference : 
http://www.developer.com/net/dealing-with-json-dates-in-asp.net-mvc.html

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and instead of returning the actual date value I just used ToString("dd MMM yyyy") on it. Then in my javascript I used new Date(datevalue), where datevalue may be "01 Jan 2009".

Comment: This should have a lot more upvotes. It's at least as good as the most upvoted ones. A little more elegant than chopping up strings. Personally, I used this but didn't recreate the date object on the front end as I just needed to display it, so I just displayed the (slightly differently) formatted string. Thanks for the tip, @Joe!

Comment: It does break separation of concerns, i.e. placing the concern of how a date is shown on the front end in the back end. But meh, it's still more elegant.

Comment: Why not use something less fragile, like [`ToString("o")`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19345594/429091)?

Comment: "dd MMM yyyy" is not supported by ECMA-262, so you should not expect the built-in parser to parse it

Answer (score 3):

See this thread:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1038457/1441866.aspx#1441866

Basically, while the `Date()` format is valid javascript, it is NOT valid JSON (there is a difference).  If you want the old format, you will probably have to create a facade and transform the value yourself, or find a way to get at the serializer for your type in the `JsonResult` and have it use a custom format for dates.

Comment: Think you meant "while the new Date() format is valid javascript" [note the "new" keyword]?

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant way but this worked for me:

```
var ms = date.substring(6, date.length - 2);
var newDate = formatDate(ms);


function formatDate(ms) {

    var date = new Date(parseInt(ms));
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var mins = date.getMinutes() + '';
    var time = "AM";

    // find time 
    if (hour >= 12) {
        time = "PM";
    }
    // fix hours format
    if (hour > 12) {
        hour -= 12;
    }
    else if (hour == 0) {
        hour = 12;
    }
    // fix minutes format
    if (mins.length == 1) {
        mins = "0" + mins;
    }
    // return formatted date time string
    return date.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + hour + ":" + mins + " " + time;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on a solution to this issue as none of the above answers really helped me.  I am working with the jquery week calendar and needed my dates to have time zone information on the server and locally on the page.  After quite a bit of digging around, I figured out a solution that may help others.

I am using asp.net 3.5, vs 2008, asp.net MVC 2, and jquery week calendar,

First, I am using a library written by Steven Levithan that helps with dealing with dates on the client side, [Steven Levithan's date library](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format).  The isoUtcDateTime format is perfect for what I needed.  In my jquery AJAX call I use the format function provided with the library with the isoUtcDateTime format and when the ajax call hits my action method, the datetime Kind is set to local and reflects the server time.

When I send dates to my page via AJAX, I send them as text strings by formatting the dates using "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'zzzz".  This format is easily converted client side using

```
var myDate = new Date(myReceivedDate);
```

Here is my complete solution minus Steve Levithan's source, which you can download:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public const string DATE_FORMAT = "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'zzzz";

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();

        return new JsonResult { Data = new { myDate = myDate.ToString(DATE_FORMAT) } };
    }

    public JsonResult ReceiveData(DateTime myDate)
    {
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { myDate = myDate.ToString(DATE_FORMAT) } };
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetData",
        type: "POST",
        cache: "false",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.myDate);
            var newDate = cleanDate(data.myDate);
            alert(newDate);
            sendData(newDate);
        }
    });
} 

function cleanDate(d) {
    if (typeof d == 'string') {
        return new Date(d) || Date.parse(d) || new Date(parseInt(d));
    }
    if (typeof d == 'number') {
        return new Date(d);
    }
    return d;
}

function sendData(newDate) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/ReceiveData",
        type: "POST",
        cache: "false",
        dataType: "json",
        data:
        {
            myDate: newDate.format("isoUtcDateTime")
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.myDate);
            var newDate = cleanDate(data.myDate);
            alert(newDate);
        }
    });
}

// bind myButton click event to call getData
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#myButton').bind('click', getData);
});
</script>
```

I hope this quick example helps out others in the same situation I was in.  At this time it seems to work very well with the Microsoft JSON Serialization and keeps my dates correct across timezones.

Comment: If you can specify the format of the date, then you should use ISO 8601 extended as that's the only format that ECMA-262 requires support for.

Answer (score 2):

The better way to handle dates in knockoutjs is to use moment library and handle dates like boss. You can easily deal with dates like /Date(-62135578800000)/. No need to bother of how your serialize date in controller.

```
function jsonToDate(date,format) {
   return moment(date).format(format);
}
```

use it like

```
var formattedDate = jsonToDate(date,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

[momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) supports lots of date time formats and utility functions on dates.

Answer (score 1):

Format the date within the query.

```
var _myModel = from _m in model.ModelSearch(word)
    select new { date = ((DateTime)_m.Date).ToShortDateString() };
```

The only problem with this solution is that you won't get any results if ANY of the date values are null.  To get around this you could either put conditional statements in your query BEFORE you select the date that ignores date nulls or you could set up a query to get all the results and then loop through all of that info using a foreach loop and assign a value to all dates that are null BEFORE you do your SELECT new.

Example of both:

```
var _test = from _t in adc.ItemSearchTest(word)
                        where _t.Date != null
                        select new { date = ((DateTime)_t.Date).ToShortDateString() };
```

The second option requires another query entirely so you can assign values to all nulls.  This and the foreach loop would have to be BEFORE your query that selects the values.

```
var _testA = from _t in adc.ItemSearchTest(word)
                         select _i;

            foreach (var detail in _testA)
            {
                if (detail.Date== null)
                {
                    detail.Date= Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/0001");
                }
            }
```

Just an idea which I found easier than all of the javascript examples.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some JavaScript code I wrote which sets an `<input type="date">` value from a date passed from ASP.NET MVC.

```
var setDate = function(id, d) {
  if (d !== undefined && d !== null) {
    var date = new Date(parseInt(d.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
    var day = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var parsedDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
    $(id).val(parsedDate);
  }
};
```

You call this function like so:

```
setDate('#productCommissionStartDate', data.commissionStartDate);
```

Where `commissionStartDate` is the JSON date passed by MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
String.prototype.jsonToDate = function(){
    try{
        var date;
        eval(("date = new " + this).replace(/\//g,''));
        return date;
    } 
    catch(e){
        return new Date(0);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be the easiest way to change it server side.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace Website
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is like MVC5's JsonResult but it uses CamelCase and date formatting.
    /// </summary>
    public class MyJsonResult : ContentResult
    {
        private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new StringEnumConverter() }
        };

        public FindersJsonResult(object obj)
        {
            this.Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Settings);
            this.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**add jquery ui plugin in your page.**

```
function JsonDateFormate(dateFormate, jsonDateTime) {
    return $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormate, eval('new ' + jsonDateTime.slice(1, -1)));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns Server Date Format. You need to define your own function.

```
function jsonDateFormat(jsonDate) {
  // Changed data format;
  return (new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)))).format("mm-dd-yyyy / h:MM tt");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not for nothing, but there is another way.  First, construct your LINQ query.  Then, construct a query of the Enumerated result and apply whatever type of formatting works for you.

```
var query = from t in db.Table select new { t.DateField };
var result = from c in query.AsEnumerable() select new { c.DateField.toString("dd MMM yyy") };
```

I have to say, the extra step is annoying, but it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to create a viewmodel that contained the date property as a string. Assigning the DateTime property from the domain model and calling the .ToString() on the date property while assigning the value to the viewmodel.

A JSON result from an MVC action method will return the date in a format compatible with the view.

### View Model

```
public class TransactionsViewModel
{
    public string DateInitiated { get; set; }
    public string DateCompleted { get; set; }
}
```

### Domain Model

```
public class Transaction{
   public DateTime? DateInitiated {get; set;}
   public DateTime? DateCompleted {get; set;}
}
```

### Controller Action Method

```
public JsonResult GetTransactions(){

var transactions = _transactionsRepository.All;
        var model = new List<TransactionsViewModel>();

        foreach (var transaction in transactions)
        {
            var item = new TransactionsViewModel
            {
                ...............
                DateInitiated = transaction.DateInitiated.ToString(),
                DateCompleted = transaction.DateCompleted.ToString(),
            };

            model.Add(item);
        }
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the controllers Json/JsonResult to return JSON.Net:

[This works a treat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348262/using-json-net-to-return-actionresult)

Answer (score 0):

Annoying, isn't it ?

My solution was to change my WCF service to get it to return DateTimes in a more readable (non-Microsoft) format.  Notice below, the "`UpdateDateOriginal`", which is WCF's default format of dates, and my "`UpdateDate`", which is formatted to something more readable.

[image]

Here's how to do it:

[Changing WCF date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511147/change-default-date-serialization-in-wcf/27860910#27860910)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a number of issues come up with JSON dates and decided to just get rid of the problem by addressing the date issue in the SQL.  Change the date format to a string format

```
select flddate from tblName

select flddate, convert(varchar(12), flddate, 113) as fldDateStr from tblName
```

By using the fldDateStr the problem dissappeared and I could still use the date field for sorting or other purposes.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest one:

var milisegundos = parseInt(data.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""));
Var newDate = new Date(milisegundos).**toLocaleDateString**("en-UE");