# German culture - get double number from JSON with a comma

Tags: c#, json, formatting, cultureinfo, culture

I have an MVC Web-API application for inner use. I have some pages with forms and numeric fields. I need to install this on a German computer, and the users will be only Germans. In Germany they write "3,5" instead of "3.5" (with a comma).

In IIS configuration the culture is "Invariant culture" and since the computer is German - the localize is "de-DE".

When the users write "3,5" in the field - I can see in firebug that "3,5" is what is sent in JSON, but the server gets it as "35".

Can I handle it on server-side? (I don't want to change the json because I'll need to do it in every field and page)

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
 using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
 public class ItemsController : ApiController, IDisposable
 {
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage UpdateItem(ItemViewModel itemVM)
        {
            // JSON data sent data.NumProp1 = "3,5"
            // itemVM.NumProp1 contains "35" instead of "3.5"
        }
}
```

Comment: JSON numbers must not be localized. You should either interpret the user input client-side and send an actual number (which uses `.`), or include the user input as a string and interpret it server-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not localize your JSON - see http://www.json.org for the spec (which only shows the dot as a separator) and [How to localize when JSON-serializing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721143/how-to-localize-when-json-serializing) for a similar question.

I wouldn't recommend trying to read your customized JSON - it may sound like a quick win right now, but in the end you simply aren't using JSON.

Comment: Please notice that I wrote that I don't want to change the data from JSON. If the user sends "3,5" - This is what is sent to the server. I just want that the server will get the right value. I don't think I understood your answer. Do I need to change "3,5" to "3.5" before sending it as JSON?

Comment: @TamarG: Yes, that is the general message. Don't send something that isn't JSON. If you *say* it is, it must be.

Comment: It's a lot of fields and pages to fix :-(

Comment: @TamarG: That's not something we can fix unfortunately... I hope they come up with a solution quickly as in the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You **must** use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on all your string formating calls when handling persitence (and JSON exchanges are technically a form of persitence):

> **Persisting Data**
>
> The InvariantCulture property can be used to persist data in a
>   culture-independent format. This provides a known format that does not
>   change and that can be used to serialize and deserialize data across
>   cultures. After the data is deserialized, it can be formatted
>   appropriately based on the cultural conventions of the current user.
>   For example, if you choose to persist date and time data in string
>   form, you can pass the InvariantCulture object to the
>   `DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)` or
>   `DateTimeOffset.ToString(IFormatProvider)` method to create the string,
>   and you can pass the InvariantCulture object to the
>   `DateTime.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)` or
>   `DateTimeOffset.Parse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)` method
>   to convert the string back to a date and time value. This technique
>   ensures that the underlying date and time values do not change when
>   the data is read or written by users from different cultures.

This applies to *all* types: numerics, decimals, floats and doubles, date and time etc. Use the invariant culture both when writing and when reading serialized data. Use invariant culture on both sides of a JSON exchange.

BTW, if you'd use the built-in JSON serializers, you'd already get this lunch for free: [JsonWriter.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Services/System/Data/Services/Serializers/JsonWriter.cs), [JsonReader.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Services/System/Data/Services/Serializers/JsonReader.cs).

Answer (score 0):

As already said: JSON is a standard, and you should *never* deviate from the standard. Doing that will make your life miserable.

If the users enter some numbers in a web form, that web form should serialize that in the correct JSON format. I think usually that is done already, if you use the right numeric types in your form, like `input type='number'`, etc. On the server end, you should read it using the [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This need for a general solution is acknowledged by the W3C, as you can see in the draft [W3C HTML JSON form submission](http://darobin.github.io/formic/specs/json/).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, if you want to just replace the German "," decimal separator with the current culture one, which makes the conversion parse correctly, use:

```
str = str.Replace(",", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
```

You can then convert your string into a numeric value using stuff like Convert.ToInt32