# Weird number conversion / encoding in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, encoding, localization, json.net

I have this iOS project that embed an unity scene as a view.
This problem occur on a device that set a localize that number has comma `,` as decimal seperator, rather than a point `.`

I sent a parameter string from native code (swift) to unity. Unity then parse the string from iOS, make a new parameters to embed in another http request.

this is the log in xcode:

```
param from iOS: 615d48538edef900126a784e***616957b6f59835001137ae7b***98.42519685039369***100.06561679790026
Request Object:
- distanceFromCeiling: 9,84251968503937E+15
- distanceFromSideWall: 1,000656167979E+16
  - Obj: : UpdateRequest
  - Obj.distanceFromCeiling: : 9,84251968503937E+15
  - Obj.distanceFromSideWall: : 1,000656167979E+16
DATA request {"distanceFromCeiling":9842519685039368.0,"distanceFromSideWall":10006561679790026.0}
```

I expected that I send `98.42519685039369, 100.06561679790026`, but for some reason, it becomes `9842519685039368.0, 10006561679790026.0` in the data request json string.

How to fix this? I have another log from a different device, with localize en-US and it seems the problem doesn't occur here.

The code in Unity (search for `is_the_problem_here` to jump right to the quetionable line:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Lean.Touch;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using BestHTTP;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

// Other functions
// ====================================

void callApiFromIOS(string param)
{
    Debug.Log("param from iOS: " + param);

    string[] str = param.Split(new string[] { "***" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    // is_the_problem_here
    System.Nullable <double> distanceFromCeiling = null;
    System.Nullable<double> distanceFromSideWall = null;

    if (str != null && str.Length >= 4)
    {
        string ceiling = str[2];
        if (!ceiling.Equals("null"))
        {
            // is_the_problem_here
            distanceFromCeiling = Convert.ToDouble(ceiling);
        }
       
        string sideWall = str[3];
        if (!sideWall.Equals("null"))
        {
            // is_the_problem_here
            distanceFromSideWall = Convert.ToDouble(sideWall);
        }
    }

    Debug.Log("Request Object: ");
    Debug.Log("- distanceFromCeiling: " + distanceFromCeiling);
    Debug.Log("- distanceFromSideWall: " + distanceFromSideWall);

    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(distanceFromCeiling, distanceFromSideWall);
    Debug.Log("  - Obj: : " + updateRequest);
    Debug.Log("  - Obj.distanceFromCeiling: : " + updateRequest.distanceFromCeiling);
    Debug.Log("  - Obj.distanceFromSideWall: : " + updateRequest.distanceFromSideWall);

    // is_the_problem_here
    string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateRequest);

    Debug.Log("DATA request " + data);

     // the rest of the code is set the json data as request body and send http.
}
```

The other log:

```
param from iOS: 615d48538edef900126a784e***616957b6f59835001137ae7b***98.42519685039369***100.06561679790026

Request Object: 
- distanceFromCeiling: 98.4251968503937
- distanceFromSideWall: 100.0656167979
  - Obj: : UpdateRequest
  - Obj.distanceFromCeiling: : 98.4251968503937
  - Obj.distanceFromSideWall: : 100.0656167979
DATA request {"distanceFromCeiling":98.425196850393689,"distanceFromSideWall":100.06561679790026}
```

** UPDATE **

I've tried following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721143/how-to-localize-when-json-serializing) but it's still not working as expect (same output as the first)

```
var converter = new FormattedDecimalConverter(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateRequest, converter);
```

The converter class:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

internal class FormattedDecimalConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private CultureInfo culture;

    public FormattedDecimalConverter(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        this.culture = culture;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToString(value, culture));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Sorry for being clueless. What am I doing wrong here?

** UPDATE **

so changing `Convert.toDouble()` to `double.Parse(ceiling, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` fix the problem. What weird issue.

Comment: See the duplicate link ... you most probably want to use the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: @derHugo sorry for being new in this, but where is the problem? as you can see, even the log is not correct (98.4251968503937 => 9,84251968503937E+15) and then output incorrect json value (9842519685039368.0)

Comment: `9,84251968503937E+15` is just another way of printing out  `9842519685039368.0`. In some cultures (e.g. french, German, etc) the `.` character is not considered the decimal splitter but rather used for decimal groups (e.g. 1.000 is not one but one thousand). Instead of `Convert` you rather want to use e.g. `double.Parse(ceiling, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` ... otherwise they will use the language settings of according device the code is executed on

Comment: It might have been in both. But actually I just read up and `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is what `JsonConvert` uses by default anyway .. so it is in `Convert.ToDouble` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per default [`Convert.ToDouble(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.convert.todouble#System_Convert_ToDouble_System_String_) uses the language/region settings of the device the code is running on.

In some cultures the `.` character is not considered as the decimal splitter but rather the decimal group character.

=> e.g. `1.000` is not one but rather one thousand!

---

If dealing with `string`s across multiple devices you should always make sure to use the cultured overload [`Convert.ToDouble(string, IFormatProvider)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todouble?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToDouble_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) and pass in the [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) which is based on `en-us`.

```
string ceiling = str[2];
if (!ceiling.Equals("null"))
{
    // is_the_problem_here
    distanceFromCeiling = Convert.ToDouble(ceiling, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
   
string sideWall = str[3];
if (!sideWall.Equals("null"))
{
    // is_the_problem_here
    distanceFromSideWall = Convert.ToDouble(sideWall, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```