# Json.Net dotnetcore 6 vs Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture / CurrentCulture vs directly set culture

Tags: c#, json.net, cultureinfo

I have the following configuration in our dotnet 6 web application, and I would like to use Json.Net serialization.

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews(ConfigureMvcOptions)
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.UseMemberCasing();
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.Culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                options.SerializerSettings.Error += (sender, args) => throw args.ErrorContext.Error;
            });
```

It is not working as I expected if I try to deserialize a decimal number like this: 99 999

The number is valid in our culture settings because we are using the " " as  decimal separator instead of comma.

If I directly set the CultrureInfo for Json.Net, the deserialization work as expected.
`options.SerializerSettings.Culture = new CultureInfo("hu-HU");`

I already checked that the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture is hungarian when the exception throw by Json.Net.  (throw args.ErrorContext.Error)

What I have missed? I know that I can write a custom serialization, howerver it would be nice if I could use the Json.Net serialization. I would not use System.Text.Json (I tried anyway with the same result) because we are upgrading a dotnet 4 MVC application.

Comment: I would suggest not using culture-specific notations for transporting values in JSON, if at all possible.

Comment: since it is a legacy application upgraded to .net core not easy to find where we send posts with / or without different UI settings. We are supporting multiple languages. Maybe we should use invariant settings when we transport data with JSON. I am going to check how many places should we change it. Thank you the suggestion

Comment: Json.NET does not use `SerializerSettings.Culture` when deserializing numbers because such JSON would be **malformed**.  The [JSON standard](https://json.org/) has a simple invariant format for numbers that is the same as the c# invariant culture's format, and so Json.NET uses that.  (`SerializerSettings.Culture` gets used for things like dates that Json.NET serializes as strings.)

Comment: But if the numbers are actually represented as localized **strings** in the JSON you could use a custom converter to deserialize them.  See [How to localize when JSON-serializing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4721143/3744182) and [Handling decimal values in Newtonsoft.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24051206/3744182).  But what exactly does your JSON file look like?    Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-6