# Convert Date into JSON object in c#

Tags: c#, json, datetime

I've created a C# class with a static method that convert's any object to a JSON object. I've used `JavaScriptSerializar` for this. Here is my code

```
public class JS
{
    public static string GetJSON(object obj)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string retJSON = js.Serialize(obj);
        return retJSON;
    }
}
```

I've another class that have only two property, `Date` & `Remark`. Here is  my class

```
public class RemarkData
{
    public DateTime Date { set; get; }
    public string Remark { set; get; }
}
```

Now, I'm converting a object of the `RemarkData` class into JSON using following code

```
JS.GetJSON(objRemarkData);
```

Here is the output I'm getting

> {"Date":"/Date(1389403352042)/","Remark":"Sme Remarks"}

Here is the output that I need

> {"Date":1389403352042,"Remark":"Some Remarks"}

What should I do tho get that kind of output? Any help ?

Comment: You will probably register your own `DateTime` converter. Does answers to this question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341719/custom-javascriptconverter-for-datetime?

Comment: That example is converting date in `dd/mm/yyyy` or some regular format that I specify. But how the date is converted into `1389403352042` this type of value?

Comment: It should be `DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double ticks = Math.Floor(objRemarkData.Date.ToUniversalTime() 
        .Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))      
        .TotalMilliseconds); 
var newob = new { Date =ticks, Remark = objRemarkData.Remark};
JS.GetJSON(newob);
```

Comment: How do you get the JSON date string "/Date(1389403352042)/" to a DateTime object though?  Just string operations to the the numeric value, and go from there?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json), it serializes Date into ISO string.

```
public class JS
{
    public static string GetJSON(object obj)
    {
        string retJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        return retJSON;
    }
}
```

Actually, you can use it directly, don't need to wrap inside another function.

This is also how asp.net web api serializes date objects. For more information why ISO string is a good choice, check out this link http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This long number is "milliseconds since epoch". We can convert this to normal javascript date by using the following snippet as explained in another so post [Converting .NET DateTime to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json)

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(1245398693390);
document.write(d);
```

One can also use a nice library from http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format with the following snippet ..

```
var newDate = dateFormat(jsonDate, "dd/mm/yyyy h:MM TT");
```