# invalid DateTime in get method

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have a variable called `TrackingDate` with the type `datatime2(7)` in sql-server and `Nullable<DateTime>` in c#. when calling my `GET` method this is what I get in my JsonResult response:

TrackingDate: `"/Date(1563271286005)/"`

But the value in my table is actually `"2019-07-16 14:31:26.0053912"`

What's the problem?

Comment: Showing your code with help the volunteers help you.

Comment: I guess `1563271286005` is your `DateTime` in `Ticks`, if you want to convert it into specific format then use `.ToString(<format>)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Comment: You've omitted all mention of your data access method and your serialization mechanism. Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it is difficult to say for sure, but based on the JsonResult you are not converting the TrackingDate variable correctly from a DateTime to a string. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057404/convert-date-into-json-object-in-c-sharp) might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the JSON serializer, serialize the date in a wrong way.

try to set the JSON serializer setting "DateFormatString" to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff"