# DateTime Objects to NSDate/NSString in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, datetime

I get date in this format from web service ( oData Web Service)

```
/Date(847065600000)
```

According to this ques. [How to handle json DateTime returned from WCF Data Services (OData)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818719/how-to-handle-json-datetime-returned-from-wcf-data-services-odata)

This is a DateTime Object. How can I convert it to a valid iOS date format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That number is a unix timestamp i.e. the seconds passed since 1970. You can convert it to NSDate with its initializer:

```
  NSTimeInterval timeInterval = 847065600000;
  NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
```

**UPDATE:**

I checked your number and it seems that it is actually in milliseconds. So you should divide it by 1000 before passing to dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: to get the correct date.

Comment: please tell me i'm not the only one that feels like kicking microsoft in the balls. in xml dates are returned in a human-readable format, this only happens with json