# Date not coming in proper format in success call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, datatables

I want to fill the data in a `gridview` so on success call, I wrote the code for that. But in response I get date value as `/Date(1518114600000)/` which seems something different.

Also for getting it right I changed the format according to my requirement. Like below

```
var createdDate = new Date(result.CREATED_DATE);
                 var createdDateRCOM = createdDate.getDate() + '/' + (createdDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + createdDate.getFullYear();
```

But still it comes like **/Date(1518114600000)/**

Here is my below code for what I wrote

```
function getDataForGrid(evt) {

        var ddlMZone = $('#ddlMaintenanceZone').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Dashboard.aspx/GetGridZoneData",
            data: JSON.stringify({ ddlMZone: ddlMZone }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                var datVal = JSON.parse(data.d);

                var details = [];
                for (var i = 0, len = datVal.length; i < len; i++) {
                    var result = datVal[i];

                    if (result.APPROVED_FLG == 0)
                    {
                        result.APPROVED_FLG = "No";
                    }

                    var buttonColumn = "<b><a href='DashboardData.aspx?id=" + result.RJ_SAPID + "' target='_blank'>Update Info</a></b>";
                    details.push([result.RJ_SAPID, result.RJ_FACILITY_ID, result.SITE_NAME, result.LATITUDE, result.LONGITUDE, result.CREATED_DATE, result.STATUS, result.APPROVED_FLG, buttonColumn]);

                }

                $('#grdMZInfo').DataTable({
                    destroy: true,
                    "aaData": details,
                    "aoColumns": [
                        { "sTitle": "RJ SapId" },
                        { "sTitle": "Facility Id" },
                        { "sTitle": "Site Name" },
                        { "sTitle": "Latitude" },
                        { "sTitle": "Longitude" },
                        { "sTitle": "Created date" },
                        { "sTitle": "Status" },
                        { "sTitle": "Approved flag" },
                        { "sTitle": "Update Data" }
                    ],
                    "bDestroy": true
                });

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('Something went wrong..!!');
            }
        });
    }
```

Please suggest what is wrong here

**update**

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetGridZoneData(string ddlMZone)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
        try
        {
            CommonDB ObjCommon = new CommonDB();
            dt = ObjCommon.GetGridZoneDataForMZ(ddlMZone);
            return DataTableToJSON(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }

    public static string DataTableToJSON(DataTable table)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> parentRow = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> childRow;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            childRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);
            }
            parentRow.Add(childRow);
        }
        return jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);
    }
```

Comment: can you post the server code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle json DateTime returned from WCF Data Services (OData)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818719/how-to-handle-json-datetime-returned-from-wcf-data-services-odata)

Comment: are you referring to createdDateRCOM  object ? is that also as createdDate ?

Comment: /Date(1518114600000)/ is the JSON dateformat. If you are looking to get date from createdDate object, you can use eval(createdDate .replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)")); regex to do that.

Comment: @G_S": yes I want to format date in `dd/mm/yy` how should I proceed

Comment: @SilentCoder: Posted the server code too. have a look

Comment: @BNN, are you formatting date at server side? or do you want to format it at client side?

Comment: @G_S:  I want it on client side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165887/discussion-between-g-s-and-bnn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any date related calculations, I personally prefer `moment js` as it has many good features and we can easily manage dates.
Its as simple as refering `moment js` file and using it.

In your case, we can just say `moment('/Date(1224043200000)/').format('DD/MM/YY')`

Comment: I tried like this, `moment(result.CREATED_DATE).format('DD/mm/YYYY')` but getting date something different such as `09/00/2018`

Answer (score 0):

In  server code I format my `DateTime` object to `string`  like below,

```
YourObject obj = new YourObject {
     startDate = dta[i].startD.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

In my Jquery,

```
 var startDate =  new Date(YourObject.startDate),
```

Above approach help me to resolve your kind of issue. Hope this will help you.