# JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize does not accept a date that was serialized by JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, javascriptserializer

How can I find the source of this problem, where a date value serialized by 
JavaScriptSerializer cannot be deserialized by the JavaScriptSerializer?

In the calling application:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(model);

// generates this json
{'Guid':'guid','OrderNumber':'1','OrderDate':'\/Date(1299456000000)\/',
   'OrderStatus':'Completed','DiscountRate':0.0000}
```

In the receiving application:

```
string json = @"{'Guid':'guid','OrderNumber':'1','OrderDate':'\/Date(1299456000000)\/',
                 'OrderStatus':'Completed','DiscountRate':0.0000}";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var model = serializer.Deserialize(json);
```

Throws a `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime` exception.

If a date is serialized by JavaScriptSerializer then why can it not be deserialized by JavaScriptSerializer?

Comment: Have you seen this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224793/javascript-serialization-of-datetime-in-asp-net-is-not-giving-a-javascript-date?

Comment: I read that and lots of other questions but still don't understand why .NET can't deserialize something that was serialized by .NET? And I'm still unsure what I need to do.  The client app is not mine, so I cant always tell them to change how they serialize it.

Comment: Try using `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer` instead. I just tried it and it didn't have any problems serializing and deserializing dates.

Answer (score 2):

If model is of type Model then try specifying the type in the call to Deserialize.

```
string json = @"{'Guid':'guid','OrderNumber':'1','OrderDate':'\/Date(1299456000000)\/',
             'OrderStatus':'Completed','DiscountRate':0.0000}";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var model = serializer.Deserialize<Model>(json);
```

I'm able to serialize and deserialize dates with no errors this way.