# Parse a JSON date serialized from UTC in format /Date(111111)/ format into a local Date object

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, utc

On the server, I have stored UTC times.  I am sending that to the client formatted as JSON, which looks like:  /Date(12211111)/.  How do I deserialize this into a local time for the user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)