# Return Json from MVC controller but Date format not proper in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working in a project where I create a grid using data from database, in my controller I have this code

```
List<IEmployeeEntity> list = new Employee(connectionString).GetEmployeeRecord();
```

It returns me list of employees with some date and further I convert it to Json using                         return Json(list);
But the date format I got in my java script grid like /Date(1325075075113)/ 
My javascript code is like

```
$.ajax({
        url: ../getRecord,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {},
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result !== "") {
                       Create Grid     
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Finally I resolve my problem by this,
List<IEmployeeEntity> list = new Employee(connectionString).GetEmployeeRecord();
return Json(list.Select(n => new
                                  {
                                    n.key1,
                                    AddedOn = n.AddedOn.Value.ToShortDateString()
                                                         : String.Empty,
                                    n.key2,
                                    n.key3
                                      }));

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not javascript issue i think you need to formate you date in you code as you required i.e in C# code only.

somthing like below might help you ..

```
List<IEmployeeEntity> list = new Employee(connectionString).GetEmployeeRecord();
list.All(x => { x.mydate = x.mydate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); return true; })
```

**or**

try this solution when your property is of type datetime because in first one it will give you an error if the property type is datetime

```
var q = from o in MyList
        select new { mydate   = x.mydate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), 
                     prop1 = o.prop1, 
                     prop2 = o.prop2
                   };
```

Comment: Yes my property is of type datetime and it is also null able. I am facing same problem yet. I tried 
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
dtfi.ShortDatePattern = "MM-dd-yyyy";
list.ForEach(f => f.AddedOn = Convert.ToDateTime(f.AddedOn, dtfi));

as well as yours.

Answer (score 1):

I had created two extension methods for such scenario

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts the value of the current System.DateTime object to its equivalent string representation using the specified format and culture-specific format information.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="date">DateTime instance</param>
/// <param name="format">A standard or custom date and time format string.</param>
/// <returns>A string representation of value of the current System.DateTime object as specified by format and provider.</returns>
public static string ToFormatString(this DateTime date, string format) {
    return date.ToString(format, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 (useful for converting C# dates to JS dates)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dt">Date Time</param>
/// <returns>Returns the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 (useful for converting C# dates to JS dates)</returns>
public static double UnixTicks(this DateTime dt) {
    DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    DateTime d2 = dt.ToUniversalTime();
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);
    return ts.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

You can choose any of them. To convert date to string you can simply do,

```
 var dateString = myDate.ToFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

You don't have to worry about the culture of the machine.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's server side (generation) issue. what's the type of date property in Employee entity. default behaviuor call its ToString() method.

Answer (score 0):

I done something like this in the this way :

put the grid into a -partial view .
from your controler insted of return json return partial view :

```
  List<IEmployeeEntity> list = new Employee(connectionString).GetEmployeeRecord();
  return PartialView("GridPartial", list);
```

In your view :
1. use : `@model IEnumerable.`
2. add a div that contains the partial:

```
  <div id="partial">
     @Html.Partial("GridPartial", @model)         
  </div>
```

and then in yout ajax :

```
$.ajax({
        url: ../getRecord,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {},
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
               if (result.indexOf("<!DOCTYPE html>") == -1) {
                      $("#partial").empty();
                      $("#partial").html(result);
                  }
                    }
                });
```

in the partial view foreach in the model (yout list) and fill the Grid...

Answer (score 0):

The JavascriptSerializer used by .Net produces that particular date format.

You can convert it to a JavaScript date with the following if you wish to format it client side:

```
var javascriptDate = new Date(parseInt(dateTimeInNetFormat.substr(6)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem for myself in the following manner:

Just add to **IEmployeeEntity** 1 extra filed that will format this DateTime  as you need and later use it on callback.

```
class IEmployeeEntity
{
   public DateTime StartDate {set; get;}

   public DateTime FormatedStartDate {  get  { return StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") } }

}
```

So just use **FormatedStartDate**  in your Javascript and you will get correct format.

or if you have some View Class you simply do

```
class IEmployeeEntity
{
   private DateTime startDate;
   public DateTime StartDate 
   { 
       set 
          { 
              startDate = value; 
          } 
       get { 
              return startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
           } 
    }
}
```

Comment: But my DateTime is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem by following

```
List<IEmployeeEntity> list = new Employee(connectionString).GetEmployeeRecord(); 
        return Json(
          list.Select(
                  n => new { 
                  n.key1, 
                  AddedOn = n.AddedOn.Value.ToShortDateString() : String.Empty, 
                  n.key2, n.key3 
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns server side date format. You need to define your own function to change date format.

```
function jsonDateFormat(jsonServerDate) {

// Changed data format;
return (new Date(parseInt(jsonServerDate.substr(6)))).format("mm-dd-yyyy / h:MM tt");
```

};