# MVC3 json Deserialize Date passed to a List in the Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, datetime, date, jquery

In a View I send the model encoded like this:

```
var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
```

to a Controller Action. The model is a list of movies, and each movies contains a release *Date*.
This is the Controller action method

```
[HttpPost]
    public void createDoc(IEnumerable<Movie> movies)
    {
        //blablabla ...
        String date = "Date:" + movies.ElementAt(i).ReleaseDate + " ";
        //print date into a file
    }
```

When I print the date it is printed as *Date:01/01/0001 00:00:00*
The serialized data passed is shown with an alert and is printed as below:
*"/Date(1070233200000)/"*

Receveing a list of movies in the createDoc controller action, I think the problem is at the beginnig: it saves in a wrong format the Date so I can't do anything to parse it in a right one.
My model Movie for the Date proprierty is:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

Do I have to change something in the model class to store the Data in the right format passing it from View post to Controller Action or can I do something before sending or after receiving json data to parse it?
Thanks.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format

Comment: I already saw it, but I think my problem is a little bit different: I think I put somehow the wrong date for each movies in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your action method your assigning the date value to a String type so why not just use string.Format... something like:

```
String date = string.Format("Date: {0:dd MM yyyy}", movies.ElementAt(i).ReleaseDate)
```

Comment: Didn't work. Seems like I put in the list the movies with the wrong dates already.