# Retrieving Date object from chrome storage not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

In a Chrome Extension, I'm trying to save a Date object to storage then read it back. According to the [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage),

> Values with a typeof "object" and "function" will typically serialize
>   to {}, with the exception of Array (serializes as expected), Date, and
>   Regex (serialize using their String representation).

I'm saving to storage as:

```
 var value= new Date(Date.now());
 chrome.storage.sync.set({"testdate":value}, function(){
     console.log("saved testdate to storage:");
     console.log(value);

 });
```

The output of logging the value is

> Tue Oct 16 2018 08:22:11 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

I'm later retrieving from storage as:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("testdate", function(items){

        console.log("test date from storage:");
        console.log(items.testdate);
});
```

In this case, the value of logging items.testdate is:

> Object
>   **proto**: constructor: ƒ Object() hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty() isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf() propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ
>   propertyIsEnumerable() toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString() toString: ƒ
>   toString() valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
>   **defineGetter**: ƒ **defineGetter**()
>   **defineSetter**: ƒ **defineSetter**()
>   **lookupGetter**: ƒ **lookupGetter**()
>   **lookupSetter**: ƒ **lookupSetter**() get **proto**: ƒ **proto**() set **proto**: ƒ **proto**()

Can't figure out how to get my Date object back (or the string representation to convert back to a Date)

Comment: Only JSONifiable part of a value is stored. To view it, type `JSON.stringify(value)` and you'll see `{}` because Date isn't JSONifiable. You can store `d.valueOf()` which is a number then recreate the date like `new Date(items.testdate)`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked in my example. In my "real" code, the date object is contained in a wrapper object (and I call JSON.stringify on the wrapper object), like `JSON.stringify(obj);`. If I'm stringifying the entire wrapper object like that, how do I override the Date object to call valueOf()? I tried `Date.prototype.toJSON = function(){ return this.valueOf(); }` but that doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: I don't know but I would make a wrapper for the storage set and get, that makes the necessary amendments in a deep copy of the object.

Answer (score 7):

#### Setting side

```
const currentTime = (new Date()).toJSON();
const items = { 'testdate': currentTime }; 
chrome.storage.local.set(items, () => {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
});
```

#### Getting side

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['testdate'], (result) => {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    } else {
        const storedJSONDate = result['testdate'];
        const testdate = new Date(storedJSONDate);
        console.log(testdate);
    }
});
```

#### Sources

I based my code off of [Date.prototype.toJSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) which says

> ```
> var jsonDate = (new Date()).toJSON();
> var backToDate = new Date(jsonDate);
>
> console.log(jsonDate); //2015-10-26T07:46:36.611Z
> ```

From the Chrome storage [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea), I think it's saying that Date won't serialize as expected. Because it specifies how Array and Regex serialize to, but not how Date serializes, I think it serializes to `{}`, which is what I got when I didn't include the `toJSON()` parts.

> An object which gives each key/value pair to update storage with. Any other key/value pairs in storage will not be affected.
>   Primitive values such as numbers will serialize as expected. Values with a typeof "object" and "function" will typically serialize to {}, with the exception of Array (serializes as expected), Date, and Regex (serialize using their String representation).

Comment: Depending on whether you want to handle exceptions, you should consider using `toISOString()`. You may want to handle exceptions where you have no control over incoming date because if you convert back an invalid date that was stored using `toJSON()` you could possibly have dates from 1969 ;) (`new Date(null)`). More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16198620/452587

Answer (score 1):

Can also use `getTime()`:

```js
//set
const currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();  //equals (new Date()).valueOf()
const items = {'testdate': currentTime};
chrome.storage.local.set(items);

//get
chrome.storage.local.get('testdate', (items) => {
    const time = items['testdate'];
    const testdate = new Date(time);
    console.log(testdate);
});
```