# Format DateTime in Kendo UI Grid using asp.net MVC Wrapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to build a Kendo UI Grid with format date dd//MM/yyyy. However, all questions that I found about this, it were resolved with code **Format("{0:d}");**. So, I have tried like a code below:

```
GridBoundColumnBuilder<TModel> builder = par.Bound(field.Name);

        switch (field.Type.Type)
        {
            case CType.Boolean:
                builder = builder.ClientTemplate(string.Format("<input type='checkbox' #= {0} ? checked='checked' : '' # disabled='disabled' ></input>", field.Name));
                break;
            case CType.Datetime:
                builder = builder.Format("{0:d}");
                break;
            case CType.Decimal:
            case CType.Double:
                builder = builder.Format("{0:0.00}");
                break;
        }
```

Another formats is works fine, just DateTime do not works.

I had this result for Datetime = /Date(1377020142000)/

Comment: how did you solve the problem?

Comment: Where you able to solve this? Using .Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}") I get it display correctly but edit doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you want to display datetime format in kendo grid then do this,

```
.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

Or

```
builder.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Or something like .Format("{0:G}")

Answer (score 35):

The other solutions were close but no cigar...  Here's what worked for me:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedDate).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(CreatedDate), 'dd/MM/yyyy') #");
```

Comment: Would this way allow for grid filtering to work correctly?

Comment: Your filtering should be done on the server side, not the client side.  You might want to try a .NET MVC equivalent to "ItemTemplate" as used here https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.filterable.itemtemplate (I couldn't easily find a .NET MVC reference for this).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll have a look into this :)

Comment: this is what worked for me, the accepted solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 15):

```
.Format("{0:" + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + "}");
```

There may be some other options in System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat that might work for you if that is not what you want.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Makes more sense to me because, why force a localized date format on somebody, unless you're sure of their actual location.

Comment: I am trying the same way as you specified but it is not working. I dont want to specify date format. It should take from culture.

Answer (score 10):

Can also use:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.DateCreate).Format("{0:G}")
```

As in http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting

Comment: Works well for display but the editor doesn't get the format and therefore shows an error message about invalid date. Any ideas?

Comment: Would making the appropriate format in your ViewModel work?

Answer (score 5):

Try instead this,this will work.

```
.ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(Date,'dd/MM/yyyy'), '" +  CurrentDateFormat + "') #");
```

Comment: Its kind of a custom template that will format your DateTime in pattern provided by you in kendo.parseDate().

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Kendo UI but it looks to me like you want to pass a string formatted date rather than a DateTime object.

The `/Date(...)/` output looks like a JSON formatted date from .Net.

I would convert the date to a string using somthing like `myDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");` before passing it to the control.

Comment: I found something similar to 
ClientTemplate("#=kendo.toString(MyPropertyDateTime,\"dd/MM/yyyy\") #");
But don't work too. I can't change my property type because I have many datas and it's hard working.

Comment: I think the problem is occurring in the javascript side of the control.  The date time there is formatted by MS as the string "/Date(...)/".  Two ways to fix it 1/. change the value being passed to a string before it gets to the control.  2/. Modify the js to cope with the date being passed like it is.

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is documented really well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format). Combining the answers there with other stuff I found, here's what I had to do to get it to work on my project.

In the C# code:

```
.Template("#= kendo.toString(parseDate(" + field.Name + "), 'dd/MM/yyyy') #");
```

Then, create a javascript function:

```
function parseDate(d) {
  d = new Date(parseInt(d.replace(/\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\//gi, "$1"), 10));
  return d;
}
```

It's a bit of a kluge, but works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers:

I format a duration in seconds in HH:MM:SS in a Kendo grid column using a ClientTemplate and calling a javascript function:

```html
                .ClientTemplate("#= secToHHMMSS(DurationInSeconds) # ")
                    .Title("Duration")
                    .Width(150);
```

```html
function secToHHMMSS(s) {
    f = Math.floor;
    g = (n) => ('00' + n).slice(-2);
    return f(s / 3600) + ':' + g(f(s / 60) % 60) + ':' + g(s % 60)
}
```