# How to format this JSON to send and receive

Tags: javascript, json, html

I have a WCF rest service that returns some JSON data and accepts some POST parameter object that are of type DateTime.

When I receive the data which contains datetime fields the date time values are like :

**"/Date(1388341800000+0530)/"**

1. How to I format to get the actual date (like 12/30/2013)
2. When I create a data for POST data like below it fails

   var dataPost = {
   ID: "121",
   Name: "Test",
   DateAdmitted: "12/30/2013"
   }

This fails (Bad request). But if I pass :

```
var dataPost = {
ID: "121",
Name: "Test",
DateAdmitted: "/Date(1388341800000+0530)/"
}
```

I want to be able to pass"12/30/2013" but these are values I deal with in my HTML.

So basically I want to :

1. Somehow format the received DateTime to readable datetime. 
   ("/Date(1388341800000+0530)/" -->   "12/30/2013")
2. While sending convert the Readable datetime to this format :
   (  "12/30/2013" --> "/Date(1388341800000+0530)/")

Can somebody please help me.

- Girija

Answer (score 1):

```
Step 1: Parse /Date(1388341800000+0530)/ extract 1388341800000 and 0530(offset)

Step 2 : create date object var d = new Date(1388341800000);


var d = new Date(1388341800000); // time
var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset)); // offset means 0530
nd.toString('yyyy-MM-dd'); // this is your date
```

Though I have not ran this code but something like this should work for you.

If i am not wrong you have asked the same question for java in another thread. Now if you can pass this properly from js then you need the java answer.

Comment: This doesnot work, My date has a offset. Can you please give me a code that works. I am not good in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

to parse the wcf service response and get the date use -

```
value = new Date(parseInt(value.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));
```

to send the wcf request use -

```
var date = '\\\/Date(' + this.getTime() + ')\\\/';
```

For your reference, check these [stackoveflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format/726869#726869)

Comment: Your code doesn't consider the timezone, which should be fairly easy to edit.

Comment: Have you tried the above shared code. Also, have you checked the reference for the similar issue?

Comment: Yes, but it doesnot consider timezone as indicated. I am not that well versed in javascript so looking for a code that works.