# Passing date value in google chart

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, google-visualization

For passing Date and time to google chart
cs code:

```
public static List<Dataes> GetData()
        {
            List<Dataes> dataList = new List<Dataes>();

            dataList.Add(new Dataes("Column 1", DateTime.ParseExact("2010-11-03 00:00:00.000", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", null)));
            dataList.Add(new Dataes("Column 2", DateTime.ParseExact("2011-11-03 00:00:00.000", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", null)));
            dataList.Add(new Dataes("Column 3", DateTime.ParseExact("2012-11-03 00:00:00.000", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", null)));
            dataList.Add(new Dataes("Column 4", DateTime.ParseExact("2013-11-03 00:00:00.000", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", null)));

            DateTime MyDateTime;
            MyDateTime = new DateTime();
            MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-11-03 00:00:00.000", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", null);
            return dataList;  


}
```

In Script code

```
  function drawVisualization(dataValues) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Column Name');
            data.addColumn('DateTime', 'Date');

            for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([dataValues[i].ColumnName, dataValues[i].MyDateTime]);
            }

            new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
                draw(data, { title: "Google Charts Example" });
        }
```

Its my brief code.Try to pass a date to google chart.but its not picking up can anyone help me resolve.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dot NET MVC (or whatever you are using) converts DateTime to a format that looks like this:

```
  "\/Date(1239018869048)\/"
```

You need to convert this to javaScript Date:

```
new Date(parseInt(dataValues[i].MyDateTime.substr(6)));
```

Look in this post [ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)