# JSON date not serialize correctly back to the client

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, datetime

I have this controller method that returns a JSON

```
public JsonResult InactiveUsers(int nbrOfInactiveDays)
{
  var results = FetchInactiveUsers(nbrOfInactiveDays);           
  return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

the content of the result is a collection of object, where the object is defines like this

```
[DataContract]
public class Inactive
{
    [DataMember]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
}
```

I already debugged to check the all the content and the `LastLoginDate` property and they all contains the date in this format `{5/17/2014 12:43:55 AM}`. But when I passed this back and do a console.log on the success call back of my ajax request the date of the first object is `invalid`

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/User/InactiveUsers/",
            cache: false,
            traditional: true,
            dataType: "json",
            data: args,
            success: function (results) {
                console.log(results);
```

the content of the console.log shows that the `LastLoginDate` property of the first item is invalid

[image]

While the rest of the date is displayed as milli-seconds and is correct.

[image]

Just wondering what could have happened? The date time in millisecond is desirable because of the widget that I am using to display the data.

Comment: Switch to JSON.Net serializer: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx or write javascript code to parse that value into a valid date time object.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format

Comment: But why is it that the first date is not serialize correctly but the rest are?