# Grabbing a list with ajax to be displayed later

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

To preface this question, I will admit that I know nothing about javascript and related topics. I am trying to have a table be created and filled out based on a button push. If I pass the data directly into the ViewModel, it displays correctly, so I know the table is working right. Here is the JQuery request:

```
<input type="button" id="RootsBtn" value="Go"/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#RootsBtn").click(function () {  
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("GetApplications"))",
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.length);
                    $('#AppTableID').show();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, throwError) {
                    alert("Error");
                    $('#AppTableID').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm basing this code loosely on code I'm using to populate a dropdown list. I know the data is being grabbed properly because the `alert(data.length);` line shows the proper number of objects in my list.

The dropdown code included a `$.each` line. I have tried using variants of this and nothing has worked for me.

How would I get the data saved into my ViewModel so that it can be displayed?

EDIT: Adding more details

This is the Table display in my view:

```
<div id="AppTableID">
    <table id="dashboard">
        <thead>
            <th>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.apps.FirstOrDefault().AppStringID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.apps.FirstOrDefault().ApplicationCategoryID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.apps.FirstOrDefault().Description)
            </th>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var item in Model.apps ?? new List<Application> { null })
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppStringID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApplicationCategoryID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my viewmodel which is passed into the view:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
         apps = new List<Application>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<Application> apps { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Application class:

```
public class Application
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string AppStringID { get; set; }
    public int? ApplicationCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

This is GetApplications: (`appService.ToList()` correctly gets the list of data. This has been well tested.)

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult GetApplications()
{
    var apps = appService.ToList();
    if (apps == null)
    {
        return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return Json(apps, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: What is the structure of the data you are returning (include your `GetApplications` method, and what html to you want to create with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the success function of your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  ....
  success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      var row = $('<tr></tr>'); // create new table row
      row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.AppStringID));
      row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.ApplicationCategoryID));
      row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.Description));
      $('#dashboard').append(row); // add to table
    });
    $('#AppTableID').show();
  },
  ....
});
```

Notes: You should probably include a `tbody` element as a child of your `table` and add the rows to that. Your `foreach` loop only needs to be `@foreach (var item in Model.apps) {..` (the collection has been initialized in the constructor). You also don't need the `if (apps == null) {..}` condition in the `GetApplications` method

Comment: It worked great. Thank you. One note, your append(row) line should have a ' after dashboard. Thanks again.

Comment: One note, Application has a few DateTime objects in it. They are being displayed like this: `/Date(1365098312483)/` . How would I get them to display correctly as a date? I'll keep looking on my own as well.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format), but an alternative would be to convert the date to a formatted string in the controller and pass that in the JSON