# Date format unrecognized

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-format

I'm writing a website that consumes a service, one of the fields returned from said service is a date / time field. However the value returning is in this format:

```
/Date(1401663600000+0100)/
```

I've been battling to convert this format in JavaScript, can anyone assist?

Comment: new Date(1401663600000+0100) outputs 
Mon Jun 02 2014 04:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time). So just get the contents within braces and pass is to new Date()

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Comment: Thanks Surender, that sorted it out, the /Date()/ thing threw me.

Answer (score 0):

new Date(1401663600000+0100) worked, the forward slash date threw me.

Comment: Probably it's not working for you. This new Date(1401663600000+0100)  will return the current date/time