# Angular UI Datepicker model binding not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML on my page

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="mdl.active_date" 
is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" close-text="Close" />
```

`mdl.active_date` is set to "/Date(1437626784877)/" when viewed in the browser console.

I'm getting the error Datepicker directive : `ng-model value must be a Date object, a number of milliseconds since 01.01.1970 or a string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If the `/` in `"/Date(1437626784877)/"` is not a typo then that's your problem. It should be a date object but you're giving it a string

Comment: That's what I thought, but this date is retrieved from a database and sent the the page via JSON, in a .net MVC app. Why would the slashes be added?

Comment: Have you checked the network log so see if the JSON response is a string or number? Need to determine if it's the server sending back `"/Date(1437626784877)/"` or if it's the client code that does it

Comment: Th JSON response string is definitely "/Date(1437626784877)/". The database field is a datetime.

Comment: Ok, that's not an angular issue then. If you can't change the server then you'll need to parse the string yourself and create a date object when you receive the response. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format) SO post or [this article](http://www.developer.com/net/dealing-with-json-dates-in-asp.net-mvc.html)

Comment: `JavascriptSerialzer` will serializes the datetime object from server as `/Date(1437626784877)/` so its your responsibility to parse the server value to date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not issue of angularjs. you can use `new Date(YourVariable)`.

```
 var datesting='/Date(1437626784877)/';
 $scope.today  =new Date(parseInt(datesting.replace('/Date(', '')));
```

Updated for date as string input.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ht8y4nw/106/)

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not support dates as their own recognized data type. Dates are serialized to strings using one of several formats when serializing (depending on the serializer), and are only sometimes deserialized to date objects when deserializing (browsers never do this by default, it's not part of the JSON spec).

The format looks like how .NET serializes dates to string within JSON. On the receiving side before working with the deserialized JSON you need to convert the date strings to date object. Neither Angular or `JSON.parse` do this for you.

You can inject custom parsing using `$httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

A `JSON.parse` implementation that includes support for dates is available here:

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jan/06/JavaScript-JSON-Date-Parsing-and-real-Dates

```
if (window.JSON && !window.JSON.dateParser) {
    var reISO = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}(?:\.\d*))(?:Z|(\+|-)([\d|:]*))?$/;
    var reMsAjax = /^\/Date\((d|-|.*)\)[\/|\\]$/;

    JSON.dateParser = function (key, value) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            var a = reISO.exec(value);
            if (a)
                return new Date(value);
            a = reMsAjax.exec(value);
            if (a) {
                var b = a[1].split(/[-+,.]/);
                return new Date(b[0] ? +b[0] : 0 - +b[1]);
            }
        }
        return value;
    };

}

var date = JSON.parse(json,JSON.dateParser);  
console.log(date);
```