# AngularJS Model DateTime property binding with format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, datetime

I have a model with many datetime properties, in this i have LastUpdatedTime property which i am using for Concurrency functionality and will not be binding to any control in view. and this datetime properties rendering in client side as /Date(1224043200000)/, while saving in mvc controller, it is not recognizing /Date(1224043200000)/ as valid format and taking default date and failing the save operation. so any common solution after fetching the model and before rendering in view, so that i can change the format for all datetime properties in the model.

Comment: Already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/726869/1565402

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim, i want angularjs method where we can convert all datetime properties in a model after fetching the model and before rendering it to view. i am not binding one Datetime property to any control in view, without binding the property i want to change the format of that property before sending to save.

Comment: check out my answer below.! **without binding the property** by this what you mean! Let me know for further help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the milliseconds part from "/Date(1224043200000)/" (1224043200000) and Convert it into valid date format and bind it into the relevant attribute of your model.

```js
var datetimeInMilliseconds = parseInt("/Date(1224043200000)/".match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1]);
var convertedDateTime = new Date(datetimeInMilliseconds);
ArrayName.AttributeName = convertedDateTime ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the date value you have in your controller as var `/Date(1224043200000)/`

**Use the below code**

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello ASP DATE ISSUE </p>
    {{dateValue.slice(6,19) | date}}
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('aspDateApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', funscope) {
  $scope.name = 'ASP DATE ISSUE';
  $scope.dateValue='/Date(1224043200000)/';
});
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/mRr8cl1sZJlfQxDqfsZ3)