# Convert Json Date and display formatted date in razor

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

In my page I have added filters, so I am using filter.js file, for that first i converted model to json object using

```
var services = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

then the rendered results display using below code

```
<script id="template" type="text/html">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title"><%= institutename %>, <%= locationname %></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="col-md-2" style="border-right:1px solid #ccc">

                            <a href="#" id="anchortrainer" class="institutemore" data-toggle="modal" rel="tooltip" data-target="#ModalInstitute" style="cursor:pointer" data-original-title='Click to know about institute'>
                                <img src="../../Images/insti1.png" alt="Coursing.in || " style="margin-top:10px" />
                            </a>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 text-center" style="border-right:1px solid #ccc; height:40px; ">
                            <p>
                                <strong class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="min-width: 85px; margin-top: 10px">
                                    <%= trainername %>
                                </strong>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 " >
                            <p class="text-center"> 
                               <%= startdate %>
                            </p> 
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </script>
```

but it displays /date(2121212)/ some thing like this in my div. so how can i convert and display formatted date to web page.

any help is appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: where i need to add this line ..

Comment: help me please, i blocked here

Comment: You can create a string property in your model to handle date formatting.

Comment: this has been answered many many times, try sending a valid date string

Comment: Also you can use javascipt. Try to apply this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26301721/1904893