# Converting date format to

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi Guys/Girls Im super new to asp.net mvc and Im trying to convert my date to a readable format. Currently it looks like this.

```
/Date(1444892163827)/
```

**My Model**

```
public class Movie
    {
        internal string title;
        internal DateTime releasedate;
        internal string genre;

        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Genre { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller

```
public JsonResult getAll()
        {
            using (MovieDBContext dataContext = new MovieDBContext())
            {
                var movieList = dataContext.Movies.ToList();
                return Json(movieList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }

        public JsonResult getMovieByNo(string MovNo)
        {
            using (MovieDBContext dataContext = new MovieDBContext())
            {
                int no = Convert.ToInt32(MovNo);
                var movieList = dataContext.Movies.Find(no);
                return Json(movieList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }
```

Any help would really be appreciated !

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/format-a-microsoft-json-date) or just return a collection of anonymous objects with the `DateTime` converted to a formatted `string`

Comment: To return anonymous objects it would be `var movieList = dataContext.Movies.Select(m => new { ID = m.ID, Title = m.Title, ReleaseDate = m.ReleaseDate.ToString(yourFormat), Genre = m.Genre });`

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you for your response this also did work :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create CustomJsonResult in MVC where you use for example JSON.Net with IsoDateTimeConverter or you should change your project MVC to WebAPI if you return only JSON.

Create class from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9302054/4599089 (Approach 2) and then use this in controller:

```
    public JsonResult getAll()
    {
        using (MovieDBContext dataContext = new MovieDBContext())
        {
            var movieList = dataContext.Movies.ToList();
            return new CustomJsonResult(){Data = movieList};
        }
    }

    public JsonResult getMovieByNo(string MovNo)
    {
        using (MovieDBContext dataContext = new MovieDBContext())
        {
            int no = Convert.ToInt32(MovNo);
            var movieList = dataContext.Movies.Find(no);
            return new CustomJsonResult(){Data = movieList};
        }

    }
```

Comment: For this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9302054/4599089 (Approach 2) you have to install Json.NET from Nuget