# Date not displaying correctly in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to display date from controller to view through jQuery in MVC4 razor.But it just displaying correctly.

[image: Date is not displaying as it is passed from controller]

To display date I used the below code:

```
$.each(data, function (index, el) {
                        console.log(el);
                        for (i = 0 ; i <el.length; i++) {
                            tr = $('<tr class="eachitem" />');
                            td = $('<td>' + el[i]["ID"] + '</td>').appendTo(tr);
                            td1 = $('<td>' + el[i]["Date"] + '</td>').appendTo(tr);
                            td1 = $('<td>' + el[i]["status"] + '</td>').appendTo(tr);

                            tr.appendTo('table');
                        }

                    });
```

Comment: In addition to Stasel's answer, you can always just format the date on the server before you return it to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the date string to a valid JavaScript date format. In order to do this use the following snippet from the answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(value.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));
```

After that, you will have a proper JavaScript date object which you can print in the format of your choice:

```
var stringDate = value.toLocaleString()
var stringDate = value.toISOString()
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript library

I can recommend using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to parse, manipulate and display dates. It takes the pain out of something quite difficult in JavaScript