# Date is not submitting by Ajax with serialize data in Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working in Ajax request to send data in Controller by using Jquery, all the fields are got fine @controller, but only one field Date("**AffectedDate**") is not coming.

can anybody tell me where 'm wrong?

**JQuery Code:**

```
function saveData() {
    var data = $("#editForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Controller/SaveTaxRate/',
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR) {
            alert('failure');                
        }
    })
}
```

**.Cs Model**:

```
public class TaxRateModel
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public double? Taxes { get; set; }
    public float? AffectedTaxRate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> AffectedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Code:**

```
public bool SaveTaxRate(TaxRateModel taxRateModel)
{
     // My Code here..
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
      <div class="span3">
          <p><strong>Country: </strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.CountryName, new { @placeholder = "Change the Country Name" })
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="span3">
            <p><strong>Tax-Rate: </strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Taxes, new { @placeholder = "Chnage the Tax-Rate", @id = "TaxRate" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="span3">
            <p><strong>Affected Tax-Rate: </strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.AffectedTaxRate, new { @placeholder = "Change the TaxRates" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="span3">
            <p><strong>Affected Date: </strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AffectedDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @placeholder = "Change the Affected Date" })                                        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thanks, but this may be different scenario i think.

Comment: Post relevant HTML markup too. Is you date serialized or not? Is your issue server side or client side?

Comment: Please write code of your form.

Comment: Here `AffectedDate` is in Controller Model and in Form you are having `FutureAffectedDate`.Both must be same for model binding.

Comment: That i had changed for fast view purpose, see now

Comment: You are changing date format to `{0:dd/MM/yyyy}` that could be a problem with server date format.

Comment: Actually, it's my requirement. let me try by removing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I used same.

```
var data = new FormData($("#editForm").get(0));
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Controller/SaveTaxRate/',
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (result) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        alert('failure');                
    }
})
```

instead of

```
var data = $("#editForm").serialize();
```

Answer (score 2):

The parsing of DateTime happens culture aware for Formvalues.

Check what you have in CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

Here is the code in the Framework:

```
if (rawValue == null && request.Form != null)
{
    culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    rawValue = request.Form.GetValues(name);
}
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization

If you need to change this behaviour you can do so by providing your own Modelbinder:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new MyModelBinder());
```

also in http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization
.

**EDIT**

because the request is send via get and the parameter is passed in the querystring the  date is parsed using invariant culture.

this part of the framework is used

```
 CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

 if (request.QueryString != null)
 {
     rawValue = request.QueryString.GetValues(name);
 }
```

I guess you should try ajays answer and use post.

Comment: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = {en-GB}

Comment: NO, But for that i need a Date in server side/Controller

Comment: Is the error happening clientside? The request is not send?

Comment: no, not any error there...date is coming in a %20 mode like.. 15%2005%201993