# why render of jquery datatable does not execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following jquery `datatable` column `'DOB'` associated with a function

```
columns:[
{
    'data': 'DOB',
    'visible': false,
    'render': function (jsonDate) {
        var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        return month + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
     }
},
]
```

but when i retrieve the value it retrieves as `Json` date `/Date(-133335000000)/` why this happens and how do i fix this?

Comment: What you are getting as `jsonDate`?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Are you saying your code (the `'render': function (jsonDate) {` function) is not working, or are you wanting to understand why the returned value is in the format `/Date(-133335000000)/` (instead of `03/24/1974`)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke why the return value in json date format not in the mm/dd/yyyy format?

Comment: I think the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format) give a good explanation. Personally, I would consider returning the value of the `DateTime` property as a formatted `string` in the controller method rather than adding this code

Comment: @StephenMuecke if im to do that, i need to modify the model class DOB type to string from DateTime... that would effect other code related to it

Comment: No, you can just return a collection of anonymous objects (which you probably should be doing anyway unless you displaying every property of the model) - `var data = db.someTable.ToList().Select(x => new { ID = x.ID, DOB = x.DOB.ToString("d"), etc ...}; return Json(data, ...);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke im not returning an anonymous collection im returning of type EmployeeDetail so in it has DOB as datetime

Comment: Yes, but you can return an anonymous object as per the code in my last comment (excepy it will be `db.EmployeeDetails.ToList()....`. That is the way I would handle it (if nothing else but to ensure only the properties required in the view are sent to the view), but there is nothing wrong with what your currently doing