# DateFormat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I wanted to achieve this format: "Saturday, August 30, 2014"

I have this code in my view:

```
{{masterlist.created_date}}
```

And the result looks like this:

```
/DATE(1452842730000)/
```

What should I do in my controller or in the view? Thanks.

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format) for an explanation of the behavior

Answer (score 1):

First of all you date should be in correct format

Use datefilter from angular
`{{masterlist.created_date | date:'fullDate'}}`

Here is the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: OP's input won't get parsed by date filter alone. Input still needs to be able to be parsed by `new Date()`

Comment: This is the format data from MVC controller: /Date(1452842730000)/

Comment: Of course you can cut your timestamp from this format and then filter him, but it'll be dirty code. You need to send a correct timestamp from your MVC controller (only timestamp 1452842730000)

Comment: how will I do it? can you give me sample?

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides many filters, among them one is for date. It provides various format to format your date. Read about them here: [date filter: angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

But filters can prove performance bottleneck, so its better to avoid them nd format your date on server side.