# display the date in the correct format in an ASP.Net App

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-5

I have to define a date in my Student Object,like that:

```
var Students = new List<Student>
{
    new Student{ FirstName="Student ",dateBirth=DateTime.Today }
};
Students.ForEach(s =>
{
    s.ObjectState = Repository.Pattern.Infrastructure.ObjectState.Added;
    context.Students.Add(s);
    context.SaveChanges();
});
```

but I get this format when I run my project:

```
[{ FirstName: "Student ", dateBirth: "/Date(1457132400000)/" }]
```

the problem is that the date format is added exactly to the DataBase Student Table (like `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`). I work with xampp MySQL
any idea please how can I solve this problem,and display the date correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Answer (score 1):

Try formatting the date time like this:

```
new Student{FirstName="Student ",dateBirth=DateTime.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")}
```

You can read up on the details here.

[Custom Date and Time Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,but I still get this problem I didn't get the DateTime in browser :(

Comment: @user3821206 How are you pulling the value back? Whichever way it is that is where you would format the date time.

Comment: sorry Sir I didn't understand your reply