# Sending a DateTime As JSON will not be displayed correctly inside my view

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application. and i have the following fields:-

```
<div>    
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LiveDate, new { @class = "datepicker", @Value = (Model != null && Model.LiveDate.HasValue) ? Model.LiveDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : string.Empty })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LiveDate)
</div>

<div>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "datepicker", disabled = "disabled",@Value = (Model != null && Model.EndDate.HasValue) ? Model.EndDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : string.Empty }) 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
</div>

<div>     
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContractLength) 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContractLength)
</div>
```

now i defined the following jquery which should send the LiveDate & ContractLength to an action method to set the EndDate:-

```
$("#LiveDate, #ContractLength").change(function () {
            $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Order/CalculateDate")", { date: $("#LiveDate").val(), month: $("#ContractLength").val() },

            function (Data) {

                $("#EndDate").val(Data.Name);


            });
        });
```

and here is the realted action method which will do the calculationspublic

```
 public   ActionResult CalculateDate(string date, int? month)
             {
                 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(date) && month.HasValue)
                 {
                     DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                     var Data = new { Name = d.AddMonths(month.Value) };
                     return Json(Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                 }
                 return Json(new { Name=string.Empty}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);




             }
```

now i tried this:-

1. the livedate = `31/05/2016`
2. contract length in month= `7`
3. the action method return the following `31/12/2016 00:00:00`
   but inside the EndDate i got this value `/Date(1483142400000)/` instead if `"31/12/2016"`.. so can anyone advice accordingly ?

Comment: This is the default serialisation behavior for MVC. [See this answer on StackOverflow for options.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Comment: @JohnMc and how i can parse the serialization ?

Comment: you should be accepting a DateTime object instead of a string. It will work once you've set the Json serialisation settings on something like Newton Soft Json.Net. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm

Comment: @JohnMc but inside my view i am parsing the date time to a string using .ToString() ... that why if i modify the action method to accept datetime i will always receive null..

Answer (score 0):

you are getting a timestamp,
use javascript functions

- toDateString
- toTimeString
- toLocaleString

or *new Date(timeStamp)* for getting a date object.

I think just *var csDate = new Date('1483142400000');* will do the job.

Note that if *dd/MM/yyyy* is important as a format your options for formating that date object will be :

- a custom function implementation that does the job of converting
- or a library like http://momentjs.com/

Comment: ok i use the following inside my script  $("#EndDate").val(Date(Data.Name)); but i got the following :- "Tue 17 May ...."

Comment: that's because of DateTime formatting, check <http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp> for how to format in the way you need it.