# To make Textbox write able only after click of Edit button in same View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.textboxfor

I have three `Textbox` which will be in readonly mode like
 `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Whatever, new {@readonly = "readonly"})` when the view will be loaded and one Edit Button. After click on Edit button i want that `Textbox` to be writeable in same `View`.
Is it possible to use same `View` or do i have to create another `View` without `@readonly = "readonly"` property for `TextBox`

Comment: You can use javascript/jquery to remove the `readonly` attribute

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke as always..Got an idea :) please put your answer in separate post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javascript/jquery to remove the `readonly` attribute, for example

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Whatever, new {@readonly = "readonly"})
<button id="edit" type="button">Edit</button>

$('#edit').click(function() {
    $('#Whatever').prop('readonly', false);
});
```

Comment: i have little bit similar question.when i click edit it pop up a screen and there i see a text box. the problem is it is not showing values on there.see my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433740/mvc-view-javascript-controller-method-javascript-div-tag  n read last comment on accepted answer

Comment: yea i want exactly like that fiddle code. i saw your code but didn't understood very well. working on it. Thanks by d way.

Comment: @HarshilShah. Sorry, I accidentally deleted the comment - I'll add it back :)

Comment: @HarshilShah, On the question you linked to, its sounds like you want something like [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yy78S3)? - no reason to go back to the server - and if the initial view is not displaying all properties of the model you want to edit, you can just add then into the view as data-* attributes

Answer (score 0):

Down here is the  `TextBox` and `Edit` button like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Whatever, new {@readonly = "readonly"})
```

and

```
<button id="edit" type="button">Edit</button>
```

then in javascript

```
$('#edit').click(function() {
    $('#Whatever').removeAttr("readonly");
});
```

This will remove the `readonly` attribute from the `TextBox`.

Comment: While using @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Whatever...), it automatically gives an id for textbox which is "Whatever". So you don't have to give additional id for it. :)