# Using a datetime string from ASP.Net MVC encoded to JSon object

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm passing a list of c# objects to my view via my viewmodel. The object has a 'EndDate' (DateTime type) as a property. Then I encode it to a Json object array to be used in Javascript. In Javascript I try to read the 'EndDate' property and then set it to a input field of type DateTime but the value is some long string that I don't recognize. How do I convert this back or use it?

Here is my code.

In my view I set the list of objects to a js variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var availableLicenses =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.AvailableLicenses));
</script>
```

When I look at the EndDate property in Chrome dev tools it looks like this.
[image]
    enter code here

I want to set this EndDate value "/Date(1501459200000)/" to a date value for a DateTime input element, but I'm not sure how to convert it?

```
<input id="EndDate"type="datetime" value="put converted date here" required>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

```
value = new Date(parseInt(value.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));
```

This is answered by [ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

The number inside parentheses is an *epoch* date (milliseconds since 1/1/1970).
The conversion to date is simple. The logic is straightforward: remove all non-digits (`\D`) and convert to Date().

```
availableLicenses.EndDate = new Date(parseInt(availableLicenses.EndDate.replace(/\D/g,'')));
console.log(availableLicenses.EndDate); 
// Date {Sun Jul 30 2017 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time)}
//note: timezone will be yours.
```