# issue with datetime jquery asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I have an issue with date.In my Model class I have used DateTime property(I used Code First), for transferring json data from action to another action I use Jquery ($.ajax), my date convert in this format, I think it milliseconds:

```
/Date(1188594000000)/
```

I tryed to convert it using js, not working: 
      `var date = new Date(mydate);`

Comment: mydate = /Date(1188594000000)/, date = invalid date outputs

Comment: you don't understand situation

Comment: I have a c# datetime like this 2017-01-03, passed this date from action to another action using jquery , in my view I get this : /Date(1188594000000)/ instead of 2017-01-03.

Comment: yes, I find the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Answer (score 1):

`/Date(1188594000000)/` is a string  and the long numbers inside the brackets are the milliseconds since the beginning of the unix epoch time. You cannot pass that(the string as it is) to `Date` constructor. If you want to generate a datetime object from that value, you should remove the first 6 characters (`/Date(`) and pass the milliseconds only

```
var mydate='/Date(1188594000000)/';
var dateVal= parseInt(mydate.substr(6));
var dateObj= new Date(dateVal);
console.log(dateObj);
```

The statement `mydate.substr(6)` will return a string value like `"1188594000000)/"` and passing this to parseInt method returns the number `1188594000000` which can be safely passed to the Date constructor.