# How to convert json date from angular in asp.net mvc

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a action method in controller which returns json result as:

```
public ActionResult GetByDids(int id)
{
    AngularMVCEntities _db = new AngularMVCEntities();
    var emps = _db.Employees.Where(x => x.Did == id).ToList();
    return Json(emps, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And a code in angular js like:

```
app.controller('employeesController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.GetEmployeesByDid = function (did) {
        alert('Get Employees By Id' + ' ' + did);
        $http.get('/Employees/GetByDids', { params: { id: did } }).then(function       (response) {
            $scope.Emps = response.data;
        });
    };
});
```

Output is:
[image]

How to convert the json DATE to string?

Comment: You need to extract the relevant date info from that string value and use it to build a Date object as needed. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074532/issue-with-datetime-jquery-asp-net-mvc/42075212#42075212

Comment: [ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to convert JSON date

```
new Date(parseInt("/Date(813694500000)/".substr(6)))
```

Result : Sat Oct 14 1995 23:45:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date = moment("/Date(1198908717056-0700)/").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Take a look at this [Angular Moment Js](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) and [Moment Js for JSON date](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/) it might be helpful.

You can convert this as the below using moment js

```
var date = moment("/Date(1198908717056-0700)/").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

To use this you have to add Angular moment in your project and which is explained in above link how to add using nuget or bower or npm.

Please find above snippet as well