# How can I parse Json dates from a Razor model

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a c# model that I am parsing into Json in my Razor view like this:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.myModel))
```

However part of myModel is a date that I need to insatiate as a Javascript date like so:

```
new Date(yyyy-MM-dd)
```

Without creating the new javascript date the date is getting parsed and read as a string.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Not clear what your asking. I assume you mean the your getting something like `/Date(1517529452191)/`?

Comment: Yes my output is similar to that, what im looking for is an output like this: Date(yyyy-MM-DD) if I format the date before adding it to my object I get an output like this "yyyy-MM-DD"

Comment: Then in your view, convert it to a `Date` using `var date = new Date(parseInt(yourValue.substr(6)));`

Comment: ^^^ should do it. Here is an explanation if you are interested. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42075212/40521

Comment: I dont have access to every instance of date as I am using this to create the Json: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.myModel))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var GetDateString= JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.myModel)));
```

This `JSON.stringify` make any value as String format.

Just to make sure that this `Model.myModel` is a true value and not a list of model itself.