# MVC Model Ajax Post with DateTime Property Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing an ajax Post with Model and everything works fine except one datetime property,I can see in network tab of browser following values are getting passed in request payload,but when I put debugger at server side action method,that datetime property showing null.

Value in Request Payload

```
DevelopmentPlan_CompletionDate:"/Date(1491796800000)/"
```

Model Property

```
 public DateTime? DevelopmentPlan_CompletionDate { get; set; }
```

It seems `/Date(1491796800000)/` format is creating issue,I am reading DateTime Value from backend Sharepoint list and value is `4/18/2017 4:00:00 AM`.Now At client side I am doing this

```
   var dataModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
   sessionStorage.setItem('DataModel', JSON.stringify(dataModel));
```

After doing above,my datetime property changes to `"/Date(1491796800000)/"` and that is causing issue when doing ajax post with this value

Comment: Show the relevant code including the ajax and how you set the property in your script - and refer [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Comment: update some findings

Comment: Don't `JSON.stringify(..)` it - just `sessionStorage.setItem('DataModel', datamodel));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because `Json.Encode()` converts `DateTime` to this format `/Date(1491796800000)/` you should use `Newtonsoft` to convert to `Json` like

```
var dataModel = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))
```

this will convert `DateTime` to this format `2017-04-11T08:55:24.659262+05:00` which can be understandable by `DateTime` and hence it is converted to `Json` format so no need to use `JSON.stringify` to convert to `Json`

```
sessionStorage.setItem('DataModel', dataModel);
```