# How to convert json date from /Date.../ to actual datetime when being returned from jsonresult?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am querying my database and returning a jsonresult, and using that to populate a grid, and I see that my date being returned is /Date(1507477743793)/. I have looked around and have seen solutions when it comes to converting one variable but not when it comes to an array of objects (I think thats right)

**EDIT**

Sample data

```
FileAReportID:1
ReportAddress:"1 Main Street West"
ReportDate:"/Date(1507477743793)/"
ReporterName:"Beetle Bailey"
```

Comment: Just for clarification which technology you are using for json response.I mean .net,java etc..

Comment: Sorry about that, I am using ajax to get the returning JSON

Comment: In which technology backend is written

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format

Comment: the backend is .NET MVC

Comment: @davidchoo12, i seen that link already, but I am talking about a bunch of records, not a single record... Ajax returns the jsonresult, and there are a number of records in there

Answer (score 0):

This number 1507477743793 is the timestamp from your server. to conver this in other format just try this:

```
let t = (new Date(1507477743793)).toUTCString();
console.log(t)

// output
and you get: 2017/12/6 05:32:30pm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom jsonresult

```
public class CustomJsonResult : JsonResult
{
    private const string _dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
        {
            response.ContentType = ContentType;
        }
        else
        {
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
        if (ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
        }
        if (Data != null)
        {
            // Using Json.NET serializer
            var isoConvert = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
            isoConvert.DateTimeFormat = _dateFormat;
            response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, isoConvert));
        }
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index() {
    return new CustomJsonResult { Data = new {  }  };
}
```

You can also create custom  MediaTypeFormatter formatter and during serialization you can change the format of datetime.

**Update**

Json.Net supports multiple ways of formatting a date, if your  consuming it from an ajax call you may want to look into `JavaScriptDateTimeConverter`.

[Serializing Dates in JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm)

Comment: I seen an example like this but I was kind of hoping to do this in jquery when the data is returned successfully from the ajax call