# Date is not displaying in correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am not that much experienced in asp.net MVC. I want to display date in correct format. But it is showing some number instead of that.

Below is my screenshot of the problem.

[image]

Here is my code where I convert date.

```
dateTime[i] = Convert.toDateTime(orderDetail.Rows[i]["joiningDate"].toString());
```

Comment: This does not seem to be a C# code. Where are these camelCase methods from? Btw here are the date format strings in C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings Please note that the string representation of each format can be different per culture. When formatting date and time, always specify the culture to avoid confusion.

Comment: That is a json format (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format))

Answer (score 1):

use this. you are not getting date in correct format so first convert it into string format and then to date time

```
Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(orderDetail.Rows[i]["joiningDate"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a date to a proper string, you can use DateTime.ToString(string format)

so:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

will display as 10-03-2018.

So on your page you'll have to use .ToString on your date, with the format you want to use.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's issue (which is because they are binding to json date value)