# DATEDIFF how to write in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a car retail system. I need to the display if I enter the correct `carid` relevant car information will be displayed in the below text boxes. I have attached the screen shot image below. I need to calculate day difference between start date and end date for calculation of how many days between because  retail fee needs to be calculated for extra days of the retail system. In C# i wrote like this `select car_id,cust_id,due,DATEDIFF(GETDATE(),due) as elap from rental where car_id = ?`
I don't know how to write in Asp.net MVC.

Code I tried:

**form design**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "return", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "popupForm" }))
        {
            <div>
                <h4> Registation</h4>
            </div>

              <div class="card-action">

                <label class="form-label">Car ID</label>
                  <input type="text" id="carno" name="carno" class="form-control" placeholder="carno" required />
            </div>



            <div class="card-action">

                <label class="form-label">Customer ID</label>

                <input type="text" id="custid" name="custid" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer ID" required />

            </div>



            <div class="card-action">

                <label class="form-label">Date</label>

                <input type="text" id="date" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" required />

            </div>


             <div class="card-action">

                <label class="form-label">Days Elapsed</label>

                 <input type="text" id="elap" name="elap" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" required />

            </div>


             <div class="card-action">

                <label class="form-label">Fine</label>

                 <input type="text" id="fine" name="fine" class="form-control" placeholder="Fine" required />

            </div>


            <div class="card">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>

        }
    </div>

</div>
```

**jQuery seach the data using jquery**

```
   <script>
        getProductcode();
        function getProductcode() {
            $("#carno").empty();
            $("#carno").keyup(function (e)
            {
                var q = $("#carno").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/return/Getid?carno=' + $("#carno").val(),
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                          $('#custid').val(data.custid);
                          $('#date').val(data.sdate);
                           $('#elap').val(data.elap);

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error)
                    {
                        //  alert("The barcode entered is not correct");
                    }
                });
                return true;
            });
        }

    </script>
```

**returnController**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Getid(String carno)
        {
            carrentEntities1 db = new carrentEntities1();
            var carn = (from s in db.rentails where s.carno == carno select s.custid).ToList();
            return Json(carn, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I don't know how to write the Datediff to calculate days. In this no result displayed. I tested `custid`, it didn't display.

**Database fields**

```
id  carno   custid  fee   sdate      edate
1   1        1     1200  2019-12-09  2019-12-19
2   1        1     20000 2019-12-01  2019-12-31
3   A0001    1     3434  2019-12-09  2019-12-27
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SqlFunctions.DateDiff` like this :

```
   var carn = (from s in db.rentails where s.carno == carno 
       select new {   
       StartDate = s.sdate,
       EndDate = s.edate,
       CarNo = s.carno,
       Fee = s.fee,
       ElapsedDays = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day",DateTime.Now,s.sdate)
    }).ToArray();
```

[Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions.datediff?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

Comment: var carn = (from s in db.rentails where s.carno == carno select s.custid).Select(t=> s.sdate {  
ElapsedDays = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day",DateTime.Now,t.edate)
}).ToArray(); error displayed

Comment: @Javafiver i forgot to put `new` keyword. And your syntax is not correct. See [anonymous types](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-anonymous-type)

Comment: var carn = (from s in db.rentails where s.carno == carno select s.custid).Select(t=> new { 
// here how to select start date
ElapsedDays = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day",DateTime.Now,t.sdate)
}).ToArray();

Comment: start sdate  enddate  edate this database table colums

Comment: @Javafiver made a valid select statement.

Comment: var carn = (from s in db.rentails where s.carno == carno) bracked closed error

Comment: Y date  diplayed on the textbox look like this /Date(1577385000000)/

Comment: @Javafiver well that's another question but the workaround described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Comment: Y date diplayed on the textbox look like this /Date(1577385000000)/  diplayed on the textbox i need to diplay 2019-12-9

Comment: if you write it is helpful for me . pls only this EndDate = s.edate,

Comment: EndDate = new Date(parseInt(s.edate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10)), i wrote like this but error

Comment: @Javafiver It should be in your javascript code in your jquery success method : ` $('#date').val( new Date(parseInt(data.sdate.substr(6))).toLocaleDateString());`

Answer (score 1):

In C# you don't need to write Datediff() function like in SQL. You just can minus needed dates:

```
var carn = (from s in db.rentails where s.carno == carno select s).
.ToList()
.Select(x => new 
{
DateDiff = (x.edate - x.sdate).Days,
//rest props
});
```

Comment: DateDiff = (x.edate - x.sdate).Days,  this line x.edate - x.sdate getting error sir

Comment: var carn = (from s in db.rentails where s.carno == carno select s).  this error indicate error

Answer (score 0):

Pls give it a try the following code:

```
var carn = (from s in db.rentails where s.carno == carno select s)
.Select(x => new 
{
  DateDiff = (x.edate - x.sdate).Days
});
```

**Note**: Make sure type of eDate, sDate is DateTime.

Comment: DateDiff = (x.edate - x.sdate).Days   in this line  Days   error

Comment: Maybe you have not used namespace for that ?

Becuz it works fine for me.

Comment: Days what is namespaces to add