# How to Split and bind json return Datetime key & value into Input text box

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

First, I have 3 input text box (day, month, year). I made Json return from my controller and I made a key & value binding function with jquery. The problem is I don't know how to split Datetime value into day, month, year and bind to my inputs because that Datetime value is looks like

`EntryDate: "/Date(940786200000)/"`

My Controller

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult getBookById(int? id)
        {
            TB_EnglishBooks tbook = db.TB_EnglishBooks.Where(x => x.ItemID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return Json(tbook, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My Html View

```
<input class="form-control" id="Day" type="text" placeholder="Day" style="width: 94px;">
<input class="form-control" id="Month" type="text" placeholder="Month" style="width: 94px;">
<input class="form-control" id="Year" type="text" placeholder="Year" style="width: 94px;">
```

My Binding Function

```
function bindcontrol(data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                $("#mymodal").modal('show');
                if (value == true || value == false) {
                    $("#addform").find("input[type='checkbox'][name='" + key + "']").prop("checked", value);
                }
                else {
                    $("#addform").find("input[name='" + key + "']").val(value);
                    $("#addform").find("textarea[name='" + key + "']").val(value);
                    $("#addform").find("select[name='" + key + "']").val(value);
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format

Comment: And if you want to perform server-side operation need to check this 
https://www.developer.com/net/dealing-with-json-dates-in-asp.net-mvc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this link

[ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Or if you want to perform server-side

https://www.developer.com/net/dealing-with-json-dates-in-asp.net-mvc.html

```
function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
  var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
  var results = pattern.exec(value);
  var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
  return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
}

function bindcontrol(data) 
{
    $.each(data, function (key, value) 
    {
        $("#mymodal").modal('show');
        if (value == true || value == false) {
            $("#addform").find("input[type='checkbox'][name='" + key + "']").prop("checked", value);
        }
        else 
        {
           if(key =="date") // here you date filed
           {
             $("#addform").find("input[name='" + key + "']").val(ToJavaScriptDate(value));
           }
           else
           {
               $("#addform").find("input[name='" + key + "']").val(value);
           }

            $("#addform").find("textarea[name='" + key + "']").val(value);
            $("#addform").find("select[name='" + key + "']").val(value);
        }
    });
}
```

> If you want perform above operation server side need to add some class
>   with `JsonTextWriter`

1) Create Json Result class

```
public class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
{
  public object Data { get; set; }

  public JsonNetResult()
  {
  }
  ...
}
```

2) Override method in controller level if you perform only controller level either you can create an attribute and register in global file as well as for all controller level.

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
  HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
  response.ContentType = "application/json";
  if (ContentEncoding != null)
    response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
  if (Data != null)
  {
   JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(response.Output) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
   JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings());
   serializer.Serialize(writer, Data);
   writer.Flush();
  }
}
```

> 3) Controller Method

```
public JsonNetResult GetOrder(DateTime id)
{
   TB_EnglishBooks tbook = db.TB_EnglishBooks.Where(x => x.ItemID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return Json(tbook, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  return new JsonNetResult() { Data=tbook};
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's perfectly worked! It bind the datetime value to only one input which name is same with the key. But I want to know how can I split that datetime in 3 part (day, month, year) and bind to my day, month, year inputs.

PS - I edited my Input tags. My input tags has no `name=""`.

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your help! It's solved now! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to help you :)