# How to extract exact date from following json string in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
public class Plans
    {
        public long PlanID { get; set; }

        public long? CompanyID { get; set; }

        public string PlanType { get; set; }

        public string PlanName { get; set; }        

        public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

        public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }       

        public int? CheckedBy { get; set; }            
    }              

    var date = [{
          0:
            BusinessType: "null"
            CheckedBy: null
            CheckedDate: null
            CompanyID: null
            CompanyName: "Swastik"
            CreatedBy: null
            CreatedDate: "/Date(1587383258707)/"    
        }];
```

Added Controller Method and ajax call from view for better assistance.Unable to find the way to do it. I am not able to find out how to extract date from above json string retrieved in jquery. Kindly assist me in that. Added  my model class above that I am using. I am simply getting data by calling a procedure and rendering the data from controller to view using ajax call and populating the ajax call sucess data in controls.

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid object.. there is a key `0` without any value. Also, this is an array, not a JSON string. Please post the correct code and update your description accordingly.

Comment: Once you've fixed that this is likely a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative Approach, what I do is create another property/ function in my Model.

your model in asp

```
    public class YourModel{
       public DateTime CreatedDate {get;set;}
        // if you want through model
        public string FormattedCreatedDate {get { return CreatedDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");}} 
        // or through functions
        public string GetFormattedCreatedDate(){
            return CreatedDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am showing this date in  label text in my view directly after extracting from above json

Comment: Isn't this from an ajax call?

Comment: yes result is coming from ajax call and after getting I am populating the html to label

Comment: Can you add your controller method?

Comment: okay, I assume UsersBal is a Model? public class UsersBal, add public string FormattedCreatedDate {get { return CreatedDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");}} as one of the properties. then see your result again. there should be a FormattedCreatedDate property there. Use that to fill your label.

Comment: getting error No overload for Method ToString takes 1 Parameter

Comment: can I see the model UsersBal?

Comment: Added my model class above

Comment: nullable DateTime, try adding 

public string FormattedCreatedDate {get { return CreatedDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");}}

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Thanks for saving my time. @Josh