# Can't convert time to ISO 8601 using C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Consider this code:

```
TimeStamp.Text = BlogComment.Date.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

`BlogComment.Date` is a `DateTime` object with its date set. `TimeStamp` is just a literal.

I keep getting unrecognised escape sequence. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a string literal - prefixing a string with @ will not parse the string for escape sequences like you have in your string but take it in "literal" form.

```
@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz"
```

**Edit:**

Also there is no `UtNow` property on DateTime - this is a static property only available on the DateTime class. You can just write:

```
TimeStamp.Text = BlogComment.Date.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

or if your intention was to convert the time to UTC:

```
TimeStamp.Text = BlogComment.Date
                            .ToUniversalTime()
                            .ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I get 'Member 'System.DateTime.UtcNow.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead'

Comment: That's because UtcNow is a static property.  Perhaps you meant ...Date.ToUniversalTime()...?

Comment: @Peter, thanks, how do I resolve that then?  I'm confused now.  All I'm trying to do is display it in this format for a Jquery plugin

Comment: var text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz"); Prefix the method with the type name.

Comment: @Ritch, thanks, but thats only for now, I need it for any given datetime that is in the past

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I'll read up more on this so I understand it fully.

Comment: @Tom: On a side note, if these dates are stored in a database, I'd recommend storing them in UTC and converting to local as needed.

Comment: Good luck. I'm glad you got the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

```
 TimeStamp.Text =  BlogComment.Date.ToUniversalTime().ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I get a red squiggle, UTC.get cannot be accessed with instance reference.

Comment: Thanks!  +1 for you, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Stamp.Text = BlogComment.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

Or

Stamp.Text = BlogComment.Date.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzzz");

My mistake: The `\` is indeed required, because it might be a custom format specifier.

And if you just want the current time, use

```
Stamp.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

UtcNow is static. It should not be accessed from an instance. It should be accessed from the class itself.

Alternatively, you might want:

```
Stamp.Text = BlogComment.Date.ToUniversalTime().ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

This would get you the universal time of the Date in BlogComment.

Comment: There is one important reason. The `:` is understood to be the (invariant) time separator in a DateTime format string. When not escaped, the `:` may be transformed to the target cultures `DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator`. Try your output by specifying the culture as Italian (`it-IT`) and you will see that that time is `2011-03-07T02.03.58.2693372+13:00`

Comment: Instead of escaping, it would be better to use the invariant format provider `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzzz", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)`

Comment: Sorry I need to correct myself. For .net DateTime formatting, `/` is the invariant date separator, and `:` is the invariant time separator.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with escaping characters in a DateTime format string, there's a similar question where [@Oppositional's writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/in-c-given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format/322305#322305)

> When using custom format strings with
>   a DateTime, it is important to remeber
>   that you need to escape your
>   seperators using single quotes.

```
string time = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(
    "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffzzz",
    DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

The characters surrounded by the single quotes `'` are literal strings inside a DateTime format string.

However, escaping the `-` and `:` is redundant if you are also specifying the Invariant culture. You should always specify the culture when formatting dates and times.

It's also important to note that `/` and `:` are the (invariant) date and time separators in a DateTime format string. DateTime.ToString will use the current cultures to transform them as necessary. For example, Italian (`it-IT`) has the `.` as its time separator. Similarly `fr-CH` has a date separator of `.`

You can see this escaping in action if you take a look at `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern` which is `yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'`

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.UtcNow..ToString("o");

(o) Roundtrip (local):. . . . 2006-04-17T14:22:48.2698750-07:00

(o) Roundtrip (UTC):. . . . . 2006-04-17T21:22:48.2698750Z

(o) Roundtrip (Unspecified):. 2000-03-20T13:02:03.0000000

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)