# Parse timestamp to this date string

Tags: java, datetime

How can I parse this timestamp

```
1594361788215
```

to data in String type in this format `2020-10-26T15:21:47.758+01:00`

Comment: Is your timestamp a number of milliseconds?

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? If not, do it first and then come back when you encounter some specific problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert timestamp to ISO860 in java,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326976/convert-timestamp-to-iso860-in-java)

Comment: `OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1594361788215L), ZoneOffset.ofHours(1)).toString()`

Answer (score 2):

You can easily format an epoch timestamp to a string with the library `java.time`.

First, you'll have to convert the epoch timestamp you have into a ZonedDateTime:

```java
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(1594361788215L), 
    ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
```

And the format you described corresponds to `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`

```java
String formatted = zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
```