# CookComputing XmlRpc Client - How to get DateTime with timezone

Tags: c#, timezone, xml-rpc, iso8601

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C#, given a DateTime object, how do I get a ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/in-c-given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)

In my .NET C# program I'm using CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll

I have an XMLRPC client that needs to connect to a xmlrpc server. I need to send an iso8601 datetime format with time zone (20121018T00:00:12+0200). So far I have tried `Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o"))`, but this returns  `<dateTime.iso8601>20121009T16:06:47</dateTime.iso8601>`, which is not the desire result I'm looking for.

Comment: Have a look at:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/in-c-given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/in-c-given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz");
```

This gives you a date similar to **2012-10-18T13:57:31.2311892-04:00**

Another way is:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
```

which gives you **2012-10-18T14:01:54.9571247Z**

To get the format you want, you can use:

```
 DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
```

Comment: the result still the same as 20121018T13:49:20. I dont know may be CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll contraining the value.

Comment: can u share d exact DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(args) u hv used?

Comment: BalanceStructRequest ssr = new BalanceStructRequest("EXT", "76639511", "1", Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")), "slapps01");
                 proxy.GetBalance(ssr);