# Formatting DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() without string.Format()

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting, iso8601

`DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()` gives me "2013/1/13 4:31:39", but I want "2012-01-13T04:31:39Z", which is very common in website's rss xml node. I am going to use this format in html5 `<time>` attribute.

I know it can be done with `.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")` , but I am thinking if there's any existing API in .NET that can do this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the Culture Info to what your culture is?

Comment: @Srikanth Venugopalan : No, I would not limit the particular culture info, because I want search engines to recognize the unique datetime for users all around the world, which must be the given "TZ" format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C#, given a DateTime object, how do I get a ISO 8601 date in string format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/in-c-given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)

Comment: FYI, you could use DateTime.UtcNow instead.

Comment: Just wanted to add the reference, where you can find many formats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does most of it except the 'T', it puts a space instead

```
dateValue.ToString("u")   //=> 2013-01-13 04:43:05Z
```

Also check out the round trip version i.e. passing "o" to [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx), only issue is it gives more precision that you seem to need

```
dateValue.ToString("o")       // => 2013-01-13T04:47:34.7559072Z
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it against the html5 validator and search engine if missing a "T" is OK.

Comment: @MaximR - yes, that's the first thing i tried. It gives you millisec which the OP doesn't seem to want.

Comment: @EdiWang - you can fix that too with a simple Replace e.g. `dateValue.ToString("u").Replace(" ","T")`

Comment: Seems bizarre to do all that, If it doesn't like the "u" or "o" output just call the ToString with the fixed format like in your question and call it a day.

Comment: @Gishu Yes. I think missing a "T" is fine, the HTML5 validator can read the time correctly. That's my purpose :)