# Manage date time issues

Tags: c#, t-sql, datetime

It is very common that application have Date issues with system date format, display format or in T-SQL statement. Currently i am in starting of new project and searching for standard solution for handling dates.

Sometimes there may be the case that client wants to change display format for all dates at application level. I want to handle such things with minimal effort without disturbing whole project code.

Please suggest me best way to handle dates in C# using .Net framework 4.0 that work with all system date format

Comment: I would suggest using a good ORM (Object relational mapping) solution that will take care of this for you.

Comment: The majority of date formatting issues arise because the data is held in strings (as opposed to more suitable data types) for any longer than necessary. Strings should be parsed as early as possible from user input, and the formatting should only be performed in the code that directly displays the dates in the output.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever +1 ,I would also add to deal only with UTC.

Comment: Thanks @Maurice Stam,@Damien_The_Unbeliever,@Royi Namir.often we get error that string is not recognised as valid date time or may be exception.which format that Convert.tostring() expect?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways but I will mention the 2 I use more often.

1. Use SqlCommand object and pass your Date parameters as DateTime to a date time field in db.
2. Use the standard SQL Date Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ttt" to pass your dates as string to a date time field in db.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Universal Dateformat would be preferred all time while passing date from application to sql weather in comparison between dates in sql; universal format of date suits and perform as per date standards.

You can use universal date format "2013-08-31 10:04:44.000" or "20130831".

And you also can create Extension Method (C# 3.0+) and use that method throughout your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your datetime object to [ISO 8601](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) format and pass it to SQL Server.

You can convert datetime to ISO 8601 as shown below and also check out [Standard Datetime format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28VS.71%29.aspx):

```
myDateTime.ToString("s")
```

For more info, please go through below thread that shows how to convert it to ISO 8601 format:

[Given a DateTime object, how do I get an ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/in-c-given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)

In database never store datetime as string but [only datetime](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/JeffS/archive/2007/08/29/SQL-Dates-and-Times.aspx) and [never format datetime at database level](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/JeffS/archive/2007/04/13/format-date-sql-server.aspx).