# How to convert java.util.date to iso 8601?

Tags: java, android, datetime

I want to convert my current system date and time to ISO 8601 in this format "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z". Please help.

Comment: Please check this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format?rq=1

Comment: Thanks alot for the solution Akhilesh Singh and Qing Xu.