# String to Datetime regardless of DateTime Format

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime

I have a text file with DateTimes stored like this: `30/11/2013 1:18:36 PM`

This is fine if you only run the program on one machine, as the DateTime is stored in the same format as the system uses. However I just encountered a problem where if I change user to one of my other accounts, who for some reason is using MM/DD/YYYY format, an error is thrown. How can I read the DateTime regardless of what the system format is? This is what I'm using right now:

```
RecieptList.Add(new Reciept
                {
                    ...
                    DateNTime = Convert.ToDateTime(stringArray[(i * 12) + 9]), // == 30/11/2013 1:18:36 PM
                    ...
                });
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think I should mention what the error was. It failed to convert the string into a datetime. +$exception {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}

Comment: Do you have the option to store the data differently?

Comment: What way were you thinking?

Comment: I was thinking that I'd want to know the time zone, and then I'd want to store the datetime as UTC. Not directly part of your question, just a common issue when doing something similar.

Comment: It seems the problem start when you write the date. If you write the date according to the CultureInfo of the current machine and then try to read back in a different culture you are at a dead end. You should store your date in a CultureInfo indipendent way. How do you write these dates?

Comment: Found a good SO question/answer explaining what I was thinking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format

Answer (score 1):

you can use `TryParseExact()` to parse the Dates.

Try This:

```
String dt = "30/11/2013 1:18:36 PM";//or anydate
DateTime result;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dt, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out result))
{
   //success use result
}
```

**Edit:** as per comments you mentioned that you are storing `dates` in system `dependent culture`.

I Strongly suggest you to use `CultureInfo.InvarientCulture` argument while storing the dates, to store them in `Indepedent culture`.

so that while reading it in different machines won't produce problems.

Try this: While storing `Dates` into `TextFile`

```
 String dt = DateObject.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

now you can write String `dt` into `TextFile`.

Comment: Sometimes the string is in dd/MM/YYYY, sometimes its MM/dd/yyyy, depeneding on what the system is set to when the date was written. Would your example read a date in MM/dd/YYYY format?

Comment: @Nathan so the Date format of the input string varies?  that isn't clear from your question.

Comment: @Nathan: 
Your task is impossible. How to determine if the date format is MM/dd/yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy. 
Take this as an example: 12/11/2013.
Is this the 12th November 2013 or 11th Dezember 2013?

Comment: @Nathan: my code assumes that your date is in the format of `dd/MM/yyyy` and it wont work if the date is in any other format.

Comment: Good point Janes, I guess the way I'm doing it now will have to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the date, with the correct settings of the computer. You can get the UI settings by calling Thread.CurrentUICulture .

```
CultureInfo ci = Thread.CurrentUICulture ; // ci refers to the current UI culture
Convert.ToDateTime(dateStr, ci);
```

Replace your code with the above , and it should work. You can find more examples below

[Convert.ToDateTime Method (String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[DateTime.TryParse Method (String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I have mentioned CurrentUICulture , there is difference between CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture

Comment: Pardon me i overlooked it.