# Need to make C# timestamp, but documentation is in Ruby

Tags: c#, ruby

I write a small program using the Vircurex API for trading e-currencies. Their documentation is using Ruby code examples and I am unsure of what the equivalent is in C#. For anyone interested, their documentation is listed here:

https://vircurex.com/welcome/api

My problem is creating the timestamp. They say it is "a UTC timestamp, must be within 5 minutes of the current time". Their example in Ruby is:

```
t = Time.now.gmtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

I can't figure out the right way to format it in C# because I am unsure of what exactly the Ruby method will return. I guess it is something like this (don't know the ???):

```
"2012-11-10???18:16:12"
```

but can someone give an example of the ruby call? I need to format the DateTime.Now-call to be in the same format.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format to get an .NET/C# solution

Comment: you can then use `irb` (or `pry`) to simulate the such kind of issues. Just run it from console, and enter the line you've specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns `"2013-12-29T17:48:17"` which is a format specified by [ISO8601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Excellent. I found a Ruby example, but it wasn't quite similar. The %dT confused me.