# Using FullCalendar with MVC 4 and C#, unable to get the start and end param values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

When my **FullCalendar** (*v 2.3.1*) attempts to get its event data in my `Controller` code, start and end parameters object looks like this:

```
start=1425186000
end=1428811200
```

The documentation states that I should be getting **ISO8601** dates as the parameters but obviously I am not.

How do I get the FullCalendar to provide **ISO8601** dates?
What are the numbers that I am actually getting?

Answer (score 1):

That is the UNIX timestamp, and in your case represents March 1, 2015 (`start`) to April 12, 2015 (`end`).

> A Unix timestamp (or epoch time) is the number of seconds that have
>   elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC. [src](http://convert-unix-time.com/)

You can get either convert the unix timestamp (shown below) or the better solution would be to simply feed the ISO date to the calendar. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format) discusses how to convert a `DateTime` to ISO.

```js
$('#fullCal').fullCalendar({
  events: [{
    title: 'Random Event',
    start: moment().add(1, 'h'),
    end: moment().add(2, 'h'),
    allDay: false
  }, {
    title: 'Your Event Unix... No work!', //this is probably what your current code is doing
    start: 1425186000,
    end: 1428811200,
    allDay: false
  }, {
    title: 'Your Event Unix... work!', //this will work
    start: moment.unix(1425186000),
    end: moment.unix(1428811200),
    allDay: false
  }],
  header: {
    left: '',
    center: 'prev title next today',
    right: ''
  },
  timezone: 'local'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div id="fullCal"></div>
```