# Is there a way to disable cache on FullCalendar?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, fullcalendar, asmx

I'm using *[FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/)* on asp.net application. I noticed that when *FullCalendar* receives data from *SQL Server* via *Web-Method > JSON*, it creates a cache file *(EventList.json)* inside browser *history/temporary* folder.

I have *cache:false* on every method but I don't know how to apply the same thing on ***events: calendar.asmx/EventList*** .

[Please refer to my other post that shows how I receive my data via web-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391891/how-to-format-asp-net-web-services-asmx-to-look-like-the-mentioned-example).

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to disable cache on events?
2. How can I use ajax like other methods to get data, because with this method I can disable cache

```js
function runCalendar() {
  var $modal = $('#event-modal');
  $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {
    // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
    // it doesn't need to have a start or end
    var eventObject = {
      title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
    };
    // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
    $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);
    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
      zIndex: 999,
      revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
      revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
    });
  });
  /*  Initialize the calendar  */
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  var form = '';
  var today = new Date($.now());

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    /* If we want to split day time each 15minutes */
    minTime: '08:00:00',
    maxTime: '20:00:00',
    timeFormat: 'HH(:mm)',
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

    events: "calendar.asmx/EventList",

    lazyFetching: false,
    allDaySlot: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    //weekends: false,
    handleWindowResize: true,
    //columnFormat:'ddd / DD',
    selectHelper: true,
    height: $(window).height() - 200,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },

    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    drop: function(date) {
      // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
      var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
      var $categoryClass = $(this).attr('data-class');
      // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
      var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
      // assign it the date that was reported
      copiedEventObject.start = date;
      if ($categoryClass) copiedEventObject['className'] = [$categoryClass];
      // render the event on the calendar
      // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
      // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
      if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
        $(this).remove();
      }
    },

    selectable: true,
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
      var form = $("<form></form>");
      form.append("<label>Change event name</label>");
      form.append("<div class='input-group'><input class='form-control' type=text value='" + calEvent.title + "' /><span class='input-group-btn'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Save</button></span></div>");
      $modal.modal({
        backdrop: 'static'
      });
      $modal.find('.delete-event').show().end().find('.save-event').hide().end().find('.modal-body').empty().prepend(form).end().find('.delete-event').unbind('click').click(function() {
        calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(ev) {

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "calendar.aspx/DeleteCalendarEvent",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{'id':'" + calEvent._id + "'}",

          });



          return (ev._id == calEvent._id);
        });


        $modal.modal('hide');
      });
      $modal.find('form').on('submit', function() {
        calEvent.title = form.find("input[type=text]").val();
        calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);

        $.ajax({
          cache: false,
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          url: "calendar.aspx/UpdateCalendarEvent",
          dataType: "json",
          data: "{'id':'" + calEvent._id + "','title':'" + calEvent.title + "'}",

        });

        $modal.modal('hide');
        return false;
      });
    },



    eventDrop: function(event, ui, jsEvent) {

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "calendar.aspx/MoveEvents",
        dataType: "json",

        data: "{'id':'" + event._id + "','start':'" + moment(event.start).format("DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss") + "','end':'" + moment(event.end).format("DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss") + "','allDay':'" + event.allDay + "'}",
      });

    },





    eventResize: function(event, allDay) {
      var allDay = !event.start.hasTime() && !event.end.hasTime();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "calendar.aspx/ResizeEvents",
        dataType: "json",

        data: "{'id':'" + event._id + "','end':'" + event.end.format("DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss") + "','allDay':'" + event.allDay + "'}",
      });


    },


    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      $modal.modal({
        backdrop: 'static'
      });
      form = $("<form></form>");
      form.append("<div class='row'></div>");
      form.find(".row")
        .append("<div class='col-md-6'><div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>Event Name</label><input class='form-control' placeholder='Insert Event Name' type='text' name='title'/></div></div>")
        .append("<div class='col-md-6'><div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>Category</label><select class='form-control' name='category'></select></div></div>")
        .find("select[name='category']")
        .append("<option value='busy'>Busy</option>")
        .append("<option value='e1'>E1</option>")
        .append("<option value='e2'>E2</option>")
        .append("<option value='bg-blue'>Lunch</option>")
        .append("<option value='bg-yellow'>Children</option></div></div>");
      inputSelect();
      $modal.find('.delete-event').hide().end().find('.save-event').show().end().find('.modal-body').empty().prepend(form).end().find('.save-event').unbind('click').click(function() {


        form.submit();

      });
      $modal.find('form').on('submit', function() {


        title = form.find("input[name='title']").val();
        beginning = form.find("input[name='beginning']").val();
        ending = form.find("input[name='ending']").val();
        $categoryClass = form.find("select[name='category'] option:checked").val();
        var allDay = !start.hasTime() && !end.hasTime();
        if (title !== null && title.length != 0) {


          //calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {

          //   title: title,
          //    start:start,
          //    end: end,
          //    allDay: false,
          //    className: $categoryClass
          //}, true);




          $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "calendar.aspx/CreateCalendarEvent",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{'title':'" + title + "','start':'" + start.format("DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss") + "','end':'" + end.format("DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss") + "','category':'" + $categoryClass + "','allDay':'" + allDay + "'}",
            success: function(data) {
              var obj = data.d;
              if (obj == 'true') {
                //$('#txtFirstName').val('');
                //$('#txtLastName').val('');
                //$('#txtCity').val('');
                //$('#txtEmailID').val('');
                //$('#lblmsg').html('Data Inserted Successfully');
              }
            },
            error: function(result) {
              alert(result);
            }
          });

          calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents')



          $modal.modal('hide');

        } else {
          alert('You have to give a title to your event');
        }
        return false;

      });


      calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    }
  });

  /* Creation of new category */
  $('.save-category').on('click', function() {
    formCategory = $('#add-category form');
    var categoryName = formCategory.find("input[name='category-name']").val();
    var categoryColor = formCategory.find("select[name='category-color']").val();
    if (categoryName !== null && categoryName.length != 0) {
      $('#external-events').append('<div class="external-event bg-' + categoryColor + '" data-class="bg-' + categoryColor + '" style="position: relative;"><i class="fa fa-move"></i>' + categoryName + '</div>')
      runCalendar();
    }

  });
}

$(function() {
  runCalendar();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
events: "calendar.asmx/EventList",
```

following method can disable the cache

```
eventSources: [{
           url: 'calendar.asmx/EventList',
           type: 'POST',
           cache: false
       }],
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [FullCalendar documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) your call already prevents the browser from caching, and the fact that FullCalendar is a jQuery plugin means that under the hood it probably uses jQuery's $.ajax() method to retrieve the data.

Comment: I understand that, however it creates that eventlist.json file as soon as FullCalendar loads... If you look at my other functions such as create,resize and etc I'm using Ajax to get my web-method but for this one which is events I don't know how to do that, because the other options have cache:false and that prevents the caching.

Comment: if you use the property events like this:  events: '@Url.Action("GetEvents","Calendar")' -> it does caching

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to turn off both lazyFetching and events cache:

```
  eventSources: [
    {
      url: ...,
      cache: false,
    }
  ],
  lazyFetching: false
```